# Biblatex: Footnote Citations independent of Footnotes, Citation Style

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing, footnotes, biblatex-chem

I am writing my PhD thesis and I want to achieve the following citation style (using `biblatex` with backend `biber`):

- Footnote citation using `/footcite` providing a short citation in the style of Angewandte Chemie (1 or 2 authors and otherwise first author *et al.*, *Journal Name* (also as hyperlink using the url) **Year**, *Volume*, first page - last page. The referencing number at the beginning of the citation should be in superscript in square brackets
- For every reference, there should be an own line in the footnote section
- The referencing number in the text should be in superscript in square brackets
- Several citation in the text at the same position should be combined, i.e. [1-4]
- If a citation is used again on the following pages, there should only be the reference number and no an additional entry in the footnote section on that page
- Footnotes should be completely independent from the citations. They should still be referenced by superscript numbers without any brackets
- The footnotes should be positioned below the citations at the end of the page with a small vertical space between the citations and the footnotes
- In the end of the document, I want a bibliography providing the full reference (all authors), which lists the entries in ascending order as mentioned in the text [1], [2], ... Since the footnotes are excluded, there would no numbers be missing

I know that this includes actually several questions, but at the moment I do not know how to start and I am happy for every piece to start with. So far, I have only used `biblatex` with `backend=biber` and `style=chem-angew`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Normally we prefer to ask one specific question per question. It can be quite beyond the scope of this site to implement a full style for you. (Though that might happen, if someone can spare the time and energy.) Maybe you can work from the style that comes closest to what you need and ask about specifics you need changed.

Comment: Is this question here now answered with your other one (http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/342485/35864)?

Comment: Yes, I would say it is despite the new questions that arose during our discussion (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/342876/how-to-cut-out-a-prefix-in-the-doi-field-if-present and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/342830/how-to-align-footnotes-citations-and-notes-while-using-individual-citation-com). Can and should I close this question so it is not marked as 'not answered' anymore?

Comment: We could vote to close it as a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/342485/35864 You should be able to do that by pressing 'close' on the bottom left on this question.

Comment: I do not see any close button. I think this requires the permission to do it (250 reputation) if I understood it correctly. You should vote for closing.