# Biblatex footcite: customizing biblatex and bibliography style

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing, biber, biblatex-chem

To built up my desired citation style ([Biblatex: Footnote Citations independent of Footnotes, Citation Style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/342012/biblatex-footnote-citations-independent-of-footnotes-citation-style)) using biblatex with backend=biber, I followed moewes advice and looked for similar approaches.

[Biblatex cite with footnote only once, with use of brackets](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20787/biblatex-cite-with-footnote-only-once-with-use-of-brackets) does most of the work and I get the following output for a standard page with several footcites and footnotes using the attached MWE which is based on Audreys answer using Joseph Wrights code.

Still, I want to change the output style to match the style of Angewandte Chemie: Authors, *Journal Name* (which should be a hyperlink using the url) **Year**, *Volume*, first page - last page. Additionally, I want to have a short version of this in the footnote citation (with 1 or 2 authors and otherwise *et al.*) and the complete citation in the bibliography in the end. How can I achieve this?

Since this question only covers the article class and I want to change it also for all the other classes: Is it possible to combine the shown approach with the biblatex-chem package, which actually provides the Angewandte Chemie style?

[image][image]

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{xcolor}                 
\usepackage{manyfoot}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric-comp,mcite,subentry]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}               
\hypersetup{%
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor={red!0!black},
    citecolor={blue!0!black},
    urlcolor={blue!80!black}
}

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{citetracker=true,sorting=none,maxcitenames=3,doi=false,url=false,isbn=false,hyperref=true,backref=false}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{
   andothers = {\textit{et~al\adddot}}            
}

% Citation footnotes: use \footnoteA
\DeclareNewFootnote{A}

% Vanilla footnotes: use \footnoteB
\DeclareNewFootnote{B}

% Number of each bibliography entry in brackets
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}

\makeatletter

\newtoggle{cbx@togcite}

% Citation number superscript in brackets
\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{%
  \iftoggle{cbx@togcite}
    {\@textsuperscript{\normalfont[\@thefnmark]}\enspace #1}
    {\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}\enspace #1}%
  \global\togglefalse{cbx@togcite}}

% Citation number superscript in brackets (for babel french)
\ifdef{\@makefntextFB}{%
\renewcommand\@makefntextFB[1]{%
  \iftoggle{cbx@togcite}
    {\@textsuperscript{\normalfont[\@thefnmark]}\enspace #1}
    {\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}\enspace #1}%
  \global\togglefalse{cbx@togcite}}}{}

%---------------------------------------------------------------
% Mostly verbatim from Joseph Wright
% http://www.texdev.net/2010/03/08/biblatex-numbered-citations-as-footnotes/

\DeclareCiteCommand{\sfcite}[\cbx@superscript]%
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \let\multicitedelim=\supercitedelim
   \iffieldundef{prenote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring prenote argument}}%
   \iffieldundef{postnote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring postnote argument}}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{sfcite}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:comp}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}}

\newbibmacro*{sfcite}{%
  \ifciteseen
  {}
  {\xappto\cbx@citehook{%
   \global\toggletrue{cbx@togcite}%
   \noexpand\footnotetextA[\thefield{labelnumber}]{%
     \fullcite{\thefield{entrykey}}\addperiod}}}}

\newrobustcmd{\cbx@superscript}[1]{%
  \mkbibsuperscript{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}%
  \cbx@citehook%
  \global\let\cbx@citehook=\empty}

\let\cbx@citehook=\empty
%---------------------------------------------------------------

\makeatother


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{Frank1953,
  author  = {Frank, F. C.},
  title   = {On spontaneous asymmetric synthesis},
  journal = {Biochim. Biophys. Acta},
  year    = {1953},
  volume  = {11},
  pages   = {459-463},
  doi     = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0006-3002(53)90082-1},
  url     = {http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0006300253900821},
}

@Article{Kagan1986,
  author  = {Puchot, C. and Samuel, O. and Dunach, E. and Zhao, S. and Agami, C. and Kagan, H. B.},
  title   = {Nonlinear effects in asymmetric synthesis. Examples in asymmetric oxidations and aldolization reactions},
  journal = {J. Am. Chem. Soc.},
  year    = {1986},
  volume  = {108},
  number  = {9},
  pages   = {2353-2357},
  doi     = {10.1021/ja00269a036},
  url     = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/ja00269a036},
}

@article{Soai1995,
   author = {Soai, Kenso and Shibata, Takanori and Morioka, Hiroshi and Choji, Kaori},
   title = {Asymmetric autocatalysis and amplification of enantiomeric excess of a chiral molecule},
   journal = {Nature},
   year = {1995},
   volume = {378},
   number = {6559},
   pages = {767-768},
   url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1038/378767a0}
}

@Article{Brown2001,
  author  = {Blackmond, Donna G. and McMillan, Christopher R. and Ramdeehul, Shailesh and Schorm, Andrea and Brown, John M.},
  title   = {Origins of Asymmetric Amplification in Autocatalytic Alkylzinc Additions},
  journal = {J. Am. Chem. Soc.},
  year    = {2001},
  volume  = {123},
  number  = {41},
  pages   = {10103-10104},
  doi     = {10.1021/ja0165133},
  url     = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/ja0165133},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
\chapter{Title}
\null\vfill\noindent
Vanilla footnote.\footnoteB{Vanilla footnote text.}
First citation.\sfcite{Frank1953}
First citation.\sfcite{Kagan1986}
Vanilla footnote.\footnoteB{Vanilla footnote text.}
First ``multi'' citation.\sfcite{Frank1953,Kagan1986,Soai1995}
\chapter{Title}
\null\vfill\noindent
Second citation.\sfcite{Frank1953}
Vanilla footnote.\footnoteB{Vanilla footnote text.}
Second citation.\sfcite{Soai1995}
Second citation.\sfcite{Kagan1986}\footnoteB{Vanilla footnote text.}
First citation.\sfcite{Brown2001}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: What are you missing if you use `style=chem-angew` instead of `style=numeric-comp`?

Comment: @moewe You're right. That actually works quite well. I had some trouble with my original code but figured out what the problem was. 
Still, how to achieve that the italic written journal name is also a hyperlink using the url of the given reference data? (And thereby suppressing the printing of the DOI if no journal data can be provided except the authors, the journal and the DOI - this is quite common if a paper was just recently accepted and published online)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the `chem-angew` style, i.e. load `style=chem-angew` instead of `style=nuemric-comp`.

Additionally you will want to look at [biblatex: make title hyperlink to DOIs, URL or ISBN](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/48400/35864) and modify the code there as follows

```
\newbibmacro{string+doiurlisbn}[1]{%
  \iffieldundef{doi}{%
    \iffieldundef{url}{%
      \iffieldundef{isbn}{%
        \iffieldundef{issn}{%
          #1%
        }{%
          \href{http://books.google.com/books?vid=ISSN\thefield{issn}}{#1}%
        }%
      }{%
        \href{http://books.google.com/books?vid=ISBN\thefield{isbn}}{#1}%
      }%
    }{%
      \href{\thefield{url}}{#1}%
    }%
  }{%
    \href{https://doi.org/\thefield{doi}}{#1}%
  }%
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{\usebibmacro{string+doiurlisbn}{\mkbibemph{#1}}}
```

In total

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{xcolor}                 
\usepackage{manyfoot}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=chem-angew,mcite,subentry]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}               
\hypersetup{%
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor={red!0!black},
    citecolor={blue!0!black},
    urlcolor={blue!80!black}
}

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{citetracker=true,sorting=none,maxcitenames=3,doi=false,url=false,isbn=false,hyperref=true,backref=false}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{
   andothers = {\textit{et~al\adddot}}            
}

% Citation footnotes: use \footnoteA
\DeclareNewFootnote{A}

% Vanilla footnotes: use \footnoteB
\DeclareNewFootnote{B}

% Number of each bibliography entry in brackets
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}

\makeatletter

\newtoggle{cbx@togcite}

% Citation number superscript in brackets
\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{%
  \iftoggle{cbx@togcite}
    {\@textsuperscript{\normalfont[\@thefnmark]}\enspace #1}
    {\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}\enspace #1}%
  \global\togglefalse{cbx@togcite}}

% Citation number superscript in brackets (for babel french)
\ifdef{\@makefntextFB}{%
\renewcommand\@makefntextFB[1]{%
  \iftoggle{cbx@togcite}
    {\@textsuperscript{\normalfont[\@thefnmark]}\enspace #1}
    {\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}\enspace #1}%
  \global\togglefalse{cbx@togcite}}}{}

%---------------------------------------------------------------
% Mostly verbatim from Joseph Wright
% http://www.texdev.net/2010/03/08/biblatex-numbered-citations-as-footnotes/

\DeclareCiteCommand{\sfcite}[\cbx@superscript]%
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \let\multicitedelim=\supercitedelim
   \iffieldundef{prenote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring prenote argument}}%
   \iffieldundef{postnote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring postnote argument}}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{sfcite}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:comp}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}}

\newbibmacro*{sfcite}{%
  \ifciteseen
  {}
  {\xappto\cbx@citehook{%
   \global\toggletrue{cbx@togcite}%
   \noexpand\footnotetextA[\thefield{labelnumber}]{%
     \fullcite{\thefield{entrykey}}\addperiod}}}}

\newrobustcmd{\cbx@superscript}[1]{%
  \mkbibsuperscript{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}%
  \cbx@citehook%
  \global\let\cbx@citehook=\empty}

\let\cbx@citehook=\empty
%---------------------------------------------------------------

\makeatother


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{Frank1953,
  author  = {Frank, F. C.},
  title   = {On spontaneous asymmetric synthesis},
  journal = {Biochim. Biophys. Acta},
  year    = {1953},
  volume  = {11},
  pages   = {459-463},
  doi     = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0006-3002(53)90082-1},
  url     = {http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0006300253900821},
}

@Article{Kagan1986,
  author  = {Puchot, C. and Samuel, O. and Dunach, E. and Zhao, S. and Agami, C. and Kagan, H. B.},
  title   = {Nonlinear effects in asymmetric synthesis. Examples in asymmetric oxidations and aldolization reactions},
  journal = {J. Am. Chem. Soc.},
  year    = {1986},
  volume  = {108},
  number  = {9},
  pages   = {2353-2357},
  doi     = {10.1021/ja00269a036},
  url     = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/ja00269a036},
}

@article{Soai1995,
   author = {Soai, Kenso and Shibata, Takanori and Morioka, Hiroshi and Choji, Kaori},
   title = {Asymmetric autocatalysis and amplification of enantiomeric excess of a chiral molecule},
   journal = {Nature},
   year = {1995},
   volume = {378},
   number = {6559},
   pages = {767-768},
   url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1038/378767a0}
}

@Article{Brown2001,
  author  = {Blackmond, Donna G. and McMillan, Christopher R. and Ramdeehul, Shailesh and Schorm, Andrea and Brown, John M.},
  title   = {Origins of Asymmetric Amplification in Autocatalytic Alkylzinc Additions},
  journal = {J. Am. Chem. Soc.},
  year    = {2001},
  volume  = {123},
  number  = {41},
  pages   = {10103-10104},
  doi     = {10.1021/ja0165133},
  url     = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/ja0165133},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\newbibmacro{string+doiurlisbn}[1]{%
  \iffieldundef{doi}{%
    \iffieldundef{url}{%
      \iffieldundef{isbn}{%
        \iffieldundef{issn}{%
          #1%
        }{%
          \href{http://books.google.com/books?vid=ISSN\thefield{issn}}{#1}%
        }%
      }{%
        \href{http://books.google.com/books?vid=ISBN\thefield{isbn}}{#1}%
      }%
    }{%
      \href{\thefield{url}}{#1}%
    }%
  }{%
    \href{https://doi.org/\thefield{doi}}{#1}%
  }%
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{\usebibmacro{string+doiurlisbn}{\mkbibemph{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Title}
\null\vfill\noindent
Vanilla footnote.\footnoteB{Vanilla footnote text.}
First citation.\sfcite{Frank1953}
First citation.\sfcite{Kagan1986}
Vanilla footnote.\footnoteB{Vanilla footnote text.}
First ``multi'' citation.\sfcite{Frank1953,Kagan1986,Soai1995}
\chapter{Title}
\null\vfill\noindent
Second citation.\sfcite{Frank1953}
Vanilla footnote.\footnoteB{Vanilla footnote text.}
Second citation.\sfcite{Soai1995}
Second citation.\sfcite{Kagan1986}\footnoteB{Vanilla footnote text.}
First citation.\sfcite{Brown2001}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

gives

[image: page one of the MWE with footnotes]

Comment: @moeve That's great - thanks! Unfortunately, my output PDF does not look the same as yours when I compile your modified code. I get an extra space - or at least an enlarged space - between the journal name and the year. This is not the case in your picture. Do you know what causes this problem?

Comment: @Sacharja I checked again and the MWE gives no enlarged space for me. Does the exact code from my answer produce the problem on your machine? Is your `biblatex` up to date? If the problem persists, please try and ask a new question with a short [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864).

Comment: It works. Thanks a lot! (And sorry for the typo in your name yesterday).
One last thing: When I download citations from ScienceDirect (elsevier), which happens quite often, the citations contain `http://dx.doi.org/` in the doi field in front of the actual doi (which is totally stupid). Is it possible to modify your code above that it is checked first if the entry in the doi field already contains `http://dx.doi.org/` in the front and only add it if necessary? For an example see the first citation of F. C. Frank in the MWE. The link does not work.

Comment: @Sacharja You should make sure that your DOI field is populated correctly. It should contain only the bare DOI, not the entire link. It should be possible to remove the `dx.doi.org` part using Biber, but that is beyond the scope of this question. Ask a new question for that.