# Repeating Citations in footnotes and normal footnotes separated using biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing, biber, biblatex-chem

I want to build up my desired citation style, using biblatex with backend=biber. So I followed the advice from Audrey, Sacharja and moewe ([Biblatex footcite: customizing biblatex and bibliography style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/342485/biblatex-footcite-customizing-biblatex-and-bibliography-style)). Which gives the following output:
[image]
[image]
[image]
I like this style very much and used it from there on. But now I tried to change it a bit so now at the end of each page there will be all citations noted which were used on the site. So for example, if the references 1,2 and 3 are used on page one and on page two there are used 2,3 and 4 it should put the references 2,3, and 4 on the bottom of page 2 and not only the ones that weren't used before. I tried it with this:[biblatex: is there a command analogous to \ifciteseen but within one page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35673/biblatex-is-there-a-command-analogous-to-ifciteseen-but-within-one-page) but couldn't bring it to work properly.

So it possible to change the code from the first example so you can quote the references on every site and still keep the footnotes under the references?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{xcolor}                 
\usepackage{manyfoot}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=chem-angew,mcite,subentry]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}               
\hypersetup{%
colorlinks,
linkcolor={red!0!black},
citecolor={blue!0!black},
urlcolor={blue!80!black}
}

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{citetracker=true,sorting=none,maxcitenames=3,
doi=false,url=false,isbn=false,hyperref=true,backref=false}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{
andothers = {\textit{et~al\adddot}}            
}

% Citation footnotes: use \footnoteA
\DeclareNewFootnote{A}

% Vanilla footnotes: use \footnoteB
\DeclareNewFootnote{B}

% Number of each bibliography entry in brackets
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}

\makeatletter

\newtoggle{cbx@togcite}

% Citation number superscript in brackets
\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{%
  \iftoggle{cbx@togcite}
    {\@textsuperscript{\normalfont[\@thefnmark]}\enspace #1}
    {\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}\enspace #1}%
  \global\togglefalse{cbx@togcite}}

% Citation number superscript in brackets (for babel french)
\ifdef{\@makefntextFB}{%
\renewcommand\@makefntextFB[1]{%
  \iftoggle{cbx@togcite}
    {\@textsuperscript{\normalfont[\@thefnmark]}\enspace #1}
    {\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}\enspace #1}%
  \global\togglefalse{cbx@togcite}}}{}

%---------------------------------------------------------------
% Mostly verbatim from Joseph Wright
% http://www.texdev.net/2010/03/08/biblatex-numbered-citations-as-footnotes/

\DeclareCiteCommand{\sfcite}[\cbx@superscript]%
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \let\multicitedelim=\supercitedelim
   \iffieldundef{prenote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring prenote argument}}%
   \iffieldundef{postnote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring postnote argument}}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{sfcite}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:comp}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}}

\newbibmacro*{sfcite}{%
  \ifciteseen
  {}
  {\xappto\cbx@citehook{%
   \global\toggletrue{cbx@togcite}%
   \noexpand\footnotetextA[\thefield{labelnumber}]{%
     \fullcite{\thefield{entrykey}}\addperiod}}}}

\newrobustcmd{\cbx@superscript}[1]{%
  \mkbibsuperscript{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}%
  \cbx@citehook%
  \global\let\cbx@citehook=\empty}

\let\cbx@citehook=\empty
%---------------------------------------------------------------

\makeatother


\begin{filecontents}{jobname.bib}
@Article{Frank1953,
  author  = {Frank, F. C.},
  title   = {On spontaneous asymmetric synthesis},
  journal = {Biochim. Biophys. Acta},
  year    = {1953},
  volume  = {11},
  pages   = {459-463},
  doi     = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0006-3002(53)90082-1},
  url     = 
  {http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0006300253900821},
  }

@Article{Kagan1986,
  author  = {Puchot, C. and Samuel, O. and Dunach, E. and Zhao, S. and 
  Agami, C. and Kagan, H. B.},
  title   = {Nonlinear effects in asymmetric synthesis. Examples in 
  asymmetric oxidations and aldolization reactions},
  journal = {J. Am. Chem. Soc.},
  year    = {1986},
  volume  = {108},
  number  = {9},
  pages   = {2353-2357},
  doi     = {10.1021/ja00269a036},
  url     = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/ja00269a036},
}

@article{Soai1995,
   author = {Soai, Kenso and Shibata, Takanori and Morioka, Hiroshi and 
   Choji, Kaori},
   title = {Asymmetric autocatalysis and amplification of enantiomeric 
   excess of a chiral molecule},
   journal = {Nature},
   year = {1995},
   volume = {378},
   number = {6559},
   pages = {767-768},
   url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1038/378767a0}
}

@Article{Brown2001,
  author  = {Blackmond, Donna G. and McMillan, Christopher R. and Ramdeehul, 
  Shailesh and Schorm, Andrea and Brown, John M.},
  title   = {Origins of Asymmetric Amplification in Autocatalytic Alkylzinc 
  Additions},
  journal = {J. Am. Chem. Soc.},
  year    = {2001},
  volume  = {123},
  number  = {41},
  pages   = {10103-10104},
  doi     = {10.1021/ja0165133},
  url     = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/ja0165133},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{jobname.bib}

\newbibmacro{string+doiurlisbn}[1]{%
  \iffieldundef{doi}{%
    \iffieldundef{url}{%
      \iffieldundef{isbn}{%
       \iffieldundef{issn}{%
          #1%
        }{%
          \href{http://books.google.com/books?vid=ISSN\thefield{issn}}{#1}%
        }%
      }{%
        \href{http://books.google.com/books?vid=ISBN\thefield{isbn}}{#1}%
      }%
    }{%
      \href{\thefield{url}}{#1}%
    }%
  }{%
    \href{https://doi.org/\thefield{doi}}{#1}%
  }%
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{\usebibmacro{string+doiurlisbn} 
{\mkbibemph{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\section{Title}
\null\vfill\noindent
Vanilla footnote.\footnoteB{Vanilla footnote text.}
First citation.\sfcite{Frank1953}
First citation.\sfcite{Kagan1986}
Vanilla footnote.\footnoteB{Vanilla footnote text.}
First ``multi'' citation.\sfcite{Frank1953,Kagan1986,Soai1995}
\newpage
\section{Title}
\null\vfill\noindent
Second citation.\sfcite{Frank1953}
Vanilla footnote.\footnoteB{Vanilla footnote text.}
Second citation.\sfcite{Soai1995}
Second citation.\sfcite{Kagan1986}\footnoteB{Vanilla footnote text.}
First citation.\sfcite{Brown2001}
\newpage
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to try and use Audrey's answer to [Repeat the same reference in footnote on different pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/71526/35864). (Incidentally there was a similar question on the German golatex.de a few days ago https://golatex.de/chronologisch-zitierte-fussnoten-mit-literaturverzeichnis-t20577.html)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{manyfoot}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=chem-angew,
  sorting=none,
  maxcitenames=3,
  subentry,
  doi=false,url=false,isbn=false,
  backref=false,
  mcite,
  citetracker,
  pagetracker=page,
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{%
  colorlinks,
  linkcolor={red!0!black},
  citecolor={blue!0!black},
  urlcolor={blue!80!black}
}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{
  andothers = {\textit{et~al\adddot}}
}

\DeclareNewFootnote{A}
\DeclareNewFootnote{B}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}

\makeatletter
\newtoggle{cbx@togcite}

% Citation number superscript in brackets
\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{%
  \iftoggle{cbx@togcite}
    {\@textsuperscript{\normalfont[\@thefnmark]}\enspace #1}
    {\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}\enspace #1}%
  \global\togglefalse{cbx@togcite}}

% Citation number superscript in brackets (for babel french)
\ifdef{\@makefntextFB}{%
\renewcommand\@makefntextFB[1]{%
  \iftoggle{cbx@togcite}
    {\@textsuperscript{\normalfont[\@thefnmark]}\enspace #1}
    {\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}\enspace #1}%
  \global\togglefalse{cbx@togcite}}}{}

% See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/71566/35864
\let\cbx@savelist\@empty
\newcounter{cbx@inst@iter}
\newcounter{cbx@inst@lastonpage}
\setcounter{cbx@inst@lastonpage}{0}

\AtDataInput{%
  \csnumgdef{cbx@instcount@\thefield{entrykey}}{-1}}

% user-level citation command
\DeclareCiteCommand{\sfcite}[\cbx@superscript]
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \let\multicitedelim\supercitedelim
   \iffieldundef{prenote}{}{\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring prenote argument}}%
   \iffieldundef{postnote}{}{\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring postnote argument}}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:super:foot}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:comp}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}}

% save instcount, save key and last inline instcount if seen first on page
\newbibmacro*{cite:super:foot}{%
  \xdef\cbx@key{\thefield{entrykey}}%
  \ifsamepage{\value{instcount}}{\csuse{cbx@instcount@\cbx@key}}
    {}
    {\listxadd{\cbx@savelist}{\cbx@key}%
     \ifnumequal{\value{cbx@inst@lastonpage}}{0}%
       {\defcounter{cbx@inst@iter}{\value{instcount}}%
        \loop\ifnum\value{cbx@inst@iter}>0
          \ifsamepage{\value{instcount}}{\value{cbx@inst@iter}}
            {\ifcsundef{blx@fnpage@\the\value{cbx@inst@iter}}
               {\setcounter{cbx@inst@lastonpage}{\value{cbx@inst@iter}}}
               {}%
             \stepcounter{cbx@inst@iter}}
            {\setcounter{cbx@inst@iter}{0}}%
        \repeat}
       {}}%
  \csnumgdef{cbx@instcount@\cbx@key}{\value{instcount}}}

\newrobustcmd*{\cbx@superscript}[1]{%
  \mkbibsuperscript{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}%
  \cbx@footnote}

% defer citation footnotes to last inline reference instance on page
\newrobustcmd*{\cbx@footnote}{%
  \ifboolexpr{ not test {\ifdefempty{\cbx@savelist}}
               and test {\ifnumequal{\value{instcount}}{\value{cbx@inst@lastonpage}}} }
    {\cbx@sortlist@init%
     \let\do\cbx@do
     \dolistloop{\cbx@sortlist}%
     \global\let\cbx@savelist\@empty
     \setcounter{cbx@inst@lastonpage}{0}}
    {}}

% print footnotes in 'sorting' order
\def\cbx@do#1{%
  \ifinlist{#1}{\cbx@savelist}
    {\begingroup
     \blx@resetdata
     \blx@getdata@cite{#1}%
     \blx@setoptions@type\abx@field@entrytype
     \blx@setoptions@entry
     \blx@execute
     \blx@beglang
     \toggletrue{cbx@togcite}%
     \footnotetextA[\thefield{labelnumber}]{\blx@driver\abx@field@entrytype}%
     \blx@endlang
     \endgroup}
    {}}

% access internal list of sorted entry keys
\def\cbx@sortlist@init{%
  \global\letcs{\cbx@sortlist}
    {blx@dlist@entry@\the\c@refsection @\blx@refcontext@context}}
\let\cbx@sortlist\@empty
\makeatother


\newbibmacro{string+doiurlisbn}[1]{%
  \iffieldundef{doi}{%
    \iffieldundef{url}{%
      \iffieldundef{isbn}{%
       \iffieldundef{issn}{%
          #1%
        }{%
          \href{http://books.google.com/books?vid=ISSN\thefield{issn}}{#1}%
        }%
      }{%
        \href{http://books.google.com/books?vid=ISBN\thefield{isbn}}{#1}%
      }%
    }{%
      \href{\thefield{url}}{#1}%
    }%
  }{%
    \href{https://doi.org/\thefield{doi}}{#1}%
  }%
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{\usebibmacro{string+doiurlisbn}
{\mkbibemph{#1}}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Frank1953,
  author  = {Frank, F. C.},
  title   = {On spontaneous asymmetric synthesis},
  journal = {Biochim. Biophys. Acta},
  year    = {1953},
  volume  = {11},
  pages   = {459-463},
  doi     = {10.1016/0006-3002(53)90082-1},
  url     =
  {http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0006300253900821},
}

@article{Kagan1986,
  author  = {Puchot, C. and Samuel, O. and Dunach, E. and Zhao, S. and
             Agami, C. and Kagan, H. B.},
  title   = {Nonlinear effects in asymmetric synthesis.
             Examples in asymmetric oxidations and aldolization reactions},
  journal = {J. Am. Chem. Soc.},
  year    = {1986},
  volume  = {108},
  number  = {9},
  pages   = {2353-2357},
  doi     = {10.1021/ja00269a036},
}
@article{Soai1995,
  author  = {Soai, Kenso and Shibata, Takanori and Morioka, Hiroshi 
             and Choji, Kaori},
  title   = {Asymmetric autocatalysis and amplification of
             enantiomeric excess of a chiral molecule},
  journal = {Nature},
  year    = {1995},
  volume  = {378},
  number  = {6559},
  pages   = {767-768},
  doi     = {10.1038/378767a0},
}
@article{Brown2001,
  author  = {Blackmond, Donna G. and McMillan, Christopher R.
             and Ramdeehul, Shailesh and Schorm, Andrea and Brown, John M.},
  title   = {Origins of Asymmetric Amplification
             in Autocatalytic Alkylzinc Additions},
  journal = {J. Am. Chem. Soc.},
  year    = {2001},
  volume  = {123},
  number  = {41},
  pages   = {10103-10104},
  doi     = {10.1021/ja0165133},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\section{Title}
\null\vfill\noindent
Vanilla footnote.\footnoteB{Vanilla footnote text.}
First citation.\sfcite{Frank1953}
First citation.\sfcite{Kagan1986}
Vanilla footnote.\footnoteB{Vanilla footnote text.}
First ``multi'' citation.\sfcite{Frank1953,Kagan1986,Soai1995}
\newpage
\section{Title}
\null\vfill\noindent
Second citation.\sfcite{Frank1953}
Vanilla footnote.\footnoteB{Vanilla footnote text.}
Second citation.\sfcite{Soai1995}
Second citation.\sfcite{Kagan1986}\footnoteB{Vanilla footnote text.}
First citation.\sfcite{Brown2001}
\newpage
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]