# How to use footcite in citation order and independently from footnotes?

Tags: citing, footnotes, koma-script

I have a KOMA book class and I want to be able to use footcite. My code looks something like this

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[backend=biber,natbib=true,style=ieee]{biblatex}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\addbibresource{sample.bib}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chap 1}
Some text\cite{greenwade93}. 


\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Which generates a references at the end of the book. But if I replace the `\cite` by a `\footcite` I get some undesired behavior.

I want a footnote to have the same number as it is in the bibliography at the end of the document. Also I want footnotes to be independent of footcites. If I do a foonote followed by citation, the footnote should not take a value that is taken by the citations.

```
Some note\footnote{This is a note} followed by a referenced 
text\footcite{greenwade93}.
```

Should return something like this

> 1: This is a note

> [1]: greenwade 1993

How do I do that?

Comment: that sounds like a very bad idea and very confusing for your readers.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer [kaobook class](https://github.com/fmarotta/kaobook) does something similar but with sidecites

Comment: You want `kaobiblio` package's `\sidecite` command to typeset the references at the bottom of the page instead of in the margin near the text? (Presumably in a block separate from the actual footnotes, not intermingled.) Do you want to do it without using the kao class and packages, or with them?

Comment: @Cicada without the kaoclass. I don’t mind if the references are in the same place as the footnotes.I will like to build an equivalent to kao’s sidecite for footnotes in a standard koma script

Comment: (a) `\sidecite` sends `\parencite{#1}: \citeauthor*{#1} (\citeyear{#1}), \citetitle{#1}` into a `marginnote`. (b) `kaobiblio` package activates biblatex's numeric compressed style: `citestyle=numeric-comp`. (c) You can do `(b)` likewise; for `(a)` as a footnote without a footnote number,  you could do footnotemark as the `\parencite`, and the corresponding footnotetext as `\parencite etc`, maybe with the parencite as text superscript. (d) Real footnote numbers and bib reference numbers will follow each other (`1,2,3,[1],4,5,[1],[1,2],6,7,...`), so a way to easily distinguish them will help.

Comment: Multiple references will be interesting puzzle for the reader: text will have `...[1]...[1]...[1]...`, and the "footnotes" will have three separate `[1]`s amongst the real footnote numbers. All the same reference, of course. Design thinking will be needed before code thinking. What output do you want to achieve, specifically?

Comment: @cicada thanks for the details. I will like to cite articles and a shorten version of it to appear in the footnote space and the full citation in the bibliography. If I cite it again I will like to keep the same number it has in the bibliography. Ideally, citations would be numbers between square brackets [120] and usual footnotes something else like exponents without brackets or something. Usual footnotes shouldn’t appear in the bibliography.

Comment: Try out the numeric compressed biblatex citation style, and then, after, the footnotemark/footnotetext technique. Kao uses a really simple method with existing tools. Your goal sounds like it is aiming for a marginnote-type at the bottom of the page technique, which is possible, but will be a build/customisation (with `\vfil` and `vbox`es etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `biblatex` with `manyfoot` package gets closer to a bottomcite:

[image: manyfoot]

The references print in citation order but are numbered according to the bibliography's alphabetical-by-family-name order.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ruled]{manyfoot}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\setlength{\textheight}{5in} % just to make a smaller picture

% Define a citation command based on \supercite
% but without superscripting
% because the footnoter command will take care of that;
% and put the bib labelnumber in []:
\DeclareCiteCommand{\superciten}%[\mkbibsuperscript]
  {\iffieldundef{prenote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring prenote argument}}%
   \iffieldundef{postnote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring postnote argument}}}
  {%
    \usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \mkbibbrackets{\usebibmacro{cite}}%
   }
  {\supercitedelim}
  {}

% Define a new foot layer called c,
% so that command \Footnotetextc becomes available:
\newfootnote{c}

% For convenience, put footnotemark/footnotetext commands 
% in a wrapper macro:
\newcommand{\bottomcite}[1]{%
\Footnotemark{\superciten{#1}}\Footnotetextc{}{\fullcite{#1}}}

\begin{document}
text\footnote{A footnote.} 
text\Footnotemark{m}\Footnotetextc{}{c note text} 
text\footnote{Another footnote.} 

xmtest\bottomcite{worman} 
xotest\Footnotemark{\superciten{nussbaum}}\Footnotetextc{}{\fullcite{nussbaum}} 
xntest\bottomcite{sigfridsson}
 
%x \autocite{aksin}


\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

---

**Edited to add**

The `biblatex` vancouver style numbers references in citation order:

[image: vancouver style]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ruled]{manyfoot}
\usepackage[style=vancouver]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\setlength{\textheight}{5in} % just to make a smaller picture

% Define a citation command based on \supercite
% but without superscripting
% because the footnoter command will take care of that;
% and put the bib labelnumber in []:
\DeclareCiteCommand{\superciten}%[\mkbibsuperscript]
  {\iffieldundef{prenote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring prenote argument}}%
   \iffieldundef{postnote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring postnote argument}}}
  {%
    \usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \mkbibbrackets{\usebibmacro{cite}}%
   }
  {\supercitedelim}
  {}

% Define a new foot layer called c,
% so that command \Footnotetextc becomes available:
\newfootnote{c}

% For convenience, put footnotemark/footnotetext commands 
% in a wrapper macro:
\newcommand{\bottomcite}[1]{%
\Footnotemark{\superciten{#1}}\Footnotetextc{}{\fullcite{#1}}}

\begin{document}
text\footnote{A footnote.} 
text\Footnotemark{m}\Footnotetextc{}{c note text} 
text\footnote{Another footnote.} 

xmtest\bottomcite{worman} 
xotest\Footnotemark{\superciten{nussbaum}}\Footnotetextc{}{\fullcite{nussbaum}} 
xntest\bottomcite{sigfridsson}
 
%x \autocite{aksin}


\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/342485/biblatex-footcite-customizing-biblatex-and-bibliography-style - a better-looking solution (and more code-y, with lots of `@`s) but still using `manyfoot`.

Answer (score 0):

A visualization:

[image: example]

Not recommendable.

Different information types shouldn't be intermingled. (e.g., Why use footnotes in the first place? Put the footnote texts inline in the main text, to see.)

Plus: Repeating the same info in the page bottom can be avoided by using only the superscripted parencite part`\textbf{\textsuperscript{\parencite{#1}}}` in the text.

And so on....

More design thought is required.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[paperheight=4in]{geometry}%for one screen image

%from kaobiblio.sty:
\usepackage[
    %style=numeric-comp,
    %citestyle=authortitle-icomp,
    citestyle=numeric-comp,
    %bibstyle=authoryear,
    bibstyle=numeric,
    sorting=none,
    %sorting=nyt,
    %sortcites=true,
    %autocite=footnote,
    backend=biber, % Compile the bibliography with biber
    hyperref=true,
    backref=true,
    citecounter=true,
    pagetracker=true,
    citetracker=true,
    ibidtracker=context,
    autopunct=true,
    autocite=plain,
]{biblatex}
%\usepackage{hyperref}

%
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}



\newcommand{\myfnmarktext}[2]{%
\textbf{\textsuperscript{\parencite{#1}}}%
{%
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\relax}%
\footnotetext%
{%
\kern-1ex{\textbf{\textsuperscript{\parencite{#1}}}}
\citeauthor*{#1} 
(\citeyear{#1}), 
\citetitle{#1}. #2%
}%
}%
}

\begin{document}


\begin{verbatim}
\parencite{#1}: \citeauthor*{#1} (\citeyear{#1}), \citetitle{#1}%
\end{verbatim}

Some text\footnote{A footnote.} and some more text\myfnmarktext{aristotle:rhetoric}{This, obviously, is a reference.}
and more text\footnote{Another footnote, but not citing \parencite{aristotle:rhetoric}.}. And the famous philosopher 
again,\myfnmarktext{aristotle:rhetoric}{This, obviously, is a reference too.}
and another normal footnote\footnote{The next footnote.}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

**Edited to add**:

`kaobook` class's use of marginnotes (for footnotes and for bibliographic references) in effect makes it a two-column layout:

[image: example kao]

From [a textboook](https://femto-physique.fr/mecanique/pdf/book_meca.pdf)

From `kaobook`'s documentation: note the repeated bib ref:

[image: kaobook]

Comment: I forgot maybe a key aspect of it. I should be able to control when the citations appears in the footnotes. Sometimes just cite and sometimes some kind of footcite. Is this possible? That avoids the double Aristotle in your example.

Comment: You control them manually. Don't type the 2nd part of the command, or make two commands. Note: they are not cites; any cites are *inside* a customized footnote command.

Comment: Also, biblatex does cite tracking, ibid tracking, opcit tracking etc (see the manual): you could do a testbool involving citecount and pageref tracking; but `kaobook` class repeats the reference each time it is referred to, so the reader does not have to move to another location (the bibliography at the end, or a footnote at the bottom of the page).

Comment: I don't get why you added that part about kaobook? Do you think it is a design problem there too?

Comment: @Mauricio as an example, and more of a design philosophy: `kaobook` is basically `scrbook`, so is transparent to it, but the *intention* of `\sidenote` and `\sidecite` is so that the reader does not have to move, even to the bottom of the page and back again. With sidenotes, footnotes and citations never intermingle, and citations are always repeated, for the convenience of the user. The reader's attention is the most precious resource you have, so ways to keep it are often sought after. (Also, kao's sidenote function sends the footnote into a sidenote even if you type `\footnote{}`.)

Comment: We can call it bottomcite if you want, it does not have to be the same type as a footnote, the same way that sidecite and sidenote in kao are different (also you can indeed do footnotes in kao as well). Bottomcite and a normal cite could be used conveniently depending on the desired result for each section. The idea was that the reader could ‘sometimes’ look at the ref right away without going to the end of the document to find it.

Comment: A marginnote in the text area, basically? (1) A box at the bottom of the page  is trivial (this site, eg copyright notice); (2) dynamically filling such a box (bottom-upwards?), and adding it to a page as the page itself is also filling up - sounds possible, but likely multi-line/multi-pass solution (like how footnotes do it, maybe?); (3) kao's `sidenote` and `sidecite` are marginnotes, one from `sidenotes` package and the other is just a normal citation in a marginnote (instead of inline, or in a footnote).

Comment: (4) yes: sidenotes are intended as replacements for footnotes, kao "Nevertheless, for completeness," leaves "`\footnote`, just in case you want to put a footnote once in a while" (manual, 3.3).

Comment: `footbib` package might help, if you are using `bibtex` package and not using `memoir` document class.