# BibLatex Chem-Angew Citation style with Postnote argument

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-chem

I'm using the chem-angew style in biblatex with footnote as described [here.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/342485/biblatex-footcite-customizing-biblatex-and-bibliography-style/342626#342626) I now need the page number in the footnotes from which I have taken the corresponding information. How can I adjust the Chem-Angew Style so that when I specify a postnote argument, it is used as the corresponding page number?
I didn't find an option like "citepages" in the documenation.

Here is a example:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt, paper=a4, twoside=false, parskip=half+, pagesize=auto, numbers=enddot, open=right, toc=listof, toc=bibliography, oneside]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[ngerman,german,english]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}                 
\usepackage{manyfoot}
\begin{filecontents}{\bibliographietest.bib}
    
    @article{Wortmann.2019,
        author = {Wortmann, Felix and Bilgeri, Dominik and Gebauer, Heiko and Lamprecht, Claudio and Fleisch, Elgar},
        year = {2019},
        title = {Geld verdienen im IoT -- aber wie?},
        pages = {1094--1112},
        pagination = {page},
        volume = {56},
        issn = {1436-3011},
        journaltitle = {HMD Praxis der Wirtschaftsinformatik},
        shortjournal = {HMD},
        shorthand = {Geld},
        doi = {10.1365/s40702-019-00561-2},
        number = {6},
        abstract = {},
        pagetotal = {19},
        file = {2508{\_}Wortmann{\_}et{\_}al-2019-HMD{\_}Praxis{\_}der{\_}Wirtschaftsinformatik:Attachments/2508{\_}Wortmann{\_}et{\_}al-2019-HMD{\_}Praxis{\_}der{\_}Wirtschaftsinformatik.pdf:application/pdf},
        note = {PII:  561}
    }
    
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=chem-angew,mcite,subentry]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliographietest.bib}
\setlength\bibitemsep{0.6\baselineskip}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}

\hypersetup{%
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor={red!0!black},
    citecolor={blue!0!black},
    urlcolor={blue!80!black}
}

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{citetracker=true,sorting=none,maxcitenames=3,doi=false,url=false,isbn=false,hyperref=true,backref=false}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{
    andothers = {\textit{et~al\adddot}}            
}

% Citation footnotes: use \footnoteA
\DeclareNewFootnote{A}

% Vanilla footnotes: use \footnoteB
\DeclareNewFootnote{B}

% Number of each bibliography entry in brackets
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}

\makeatletter

\newtoggle{cbx@togcite}

% Citation number superscript in brackets
\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{%
    \setstretch{1.0}
    \iftoggle{cbx@togcite}
    {\@textsuperscript{\normalfont[\@thefnmark]}\enspace #1}
    {\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}\enspace #1}%
    \global\togglefalse{cbx@togcite}}

% Citation number superscript in brackets (for babel french)
\ifdef{\@makefntextFB}{%
    \renewcommand\@makefntextFB[1]{%
        \setstretch{1.0}
        \iftoggle{cbx@togcite}
        {\@textsuperscript{\normalfont[\@thefnmark]}\enspace #1}
        {\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}\enspace #1}%
        \global\togglefalse{cbx@togcite}}}{}

%---------------------------------------------------------------
% Mostly verbatim from Joseph Wright
% http://www.texdev.net/2010/03/08/biblatex-numbered-citations-as-footnotes/

\DeclareCiteCommand{\sfcite}[\cbx@superscript]%
{\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
    \let\multicitedelim=\supercitedelim
    \iffieldundef{prenote}
    {}
    {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring prenote argument}}%
    \iffieldundef{postnote}
    {}
    {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring postnote argument}}}
{\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
    \usebibmacro{sfcite}%
    \usebibmacro{cite:comp}}
{}
{\usebibmacro{cite:dump}}

\newbibmacro*{sfcite}{%
    \ifciteseen
    {}
    {\xappto\cbx@citehook{%
            \global\toggletrue{cbx@togcite}%
            \noexpand\footnotetextA[\thefield{labelnumber}]{%
                \fullcite{\thefield{entrykey}}\addperiod}}}}

\newrobustcmd{\cbx@superscript}[1]{%
    \mkbibsuperscript{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}%
    \cbx@citehook%
    \global\let\cbx@citehook=\empty}

\let\cbx@citehook=\empty
%---------------------------------------------------------------

\makeatother

\newbibmacro{string+doiurlisbn}[1]{%
    \iffieldundef{doi}{%
        \iffieldundef{url}{%
            \iffieldundef{isbn}{%
                \iffieldundef{issn}{%
                    #1%
                }{%
                    \href{http://books.google.com/books?vid=ISSN\thefield{issn}}{#1}%
                }%
            }{%
                \href{http://books.google.com/books?vid=ISBN\thefield{isbn}}{#1}%
            }%
        }{%
            \href{\thefield{url}}{#1}%
        }%
    }{%
        \href{https://doi.org/\thefield{doi}}{#1}%
    }%
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{\usebibmacro{string+doiurlisbn}{\mkbibemph{#1}}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,incollection,misc,phdthesis,book,inproceedings]{title}%
{\usebibmacro{string+doiurlisbn}{\mkbibquote{#1}}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{\usebibmacro{string+doiurlisbn}{\mkbibemph{#1}}}


\begin{document}
    Text \sfcite{Wortmann.2019}
\end{document}
```

Here is how I want it to look like:
[image]

So the page range of the whole article in the journal should be left out, so I can define a postnote argument with the page. Also the first 1.0 is not visible in my working document, don't know why it is on display in this example.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: And maybe add an image or example of what you want, as it is not very clear now.

Comment: Added an example and a picture, how I want it to look like. Thanks @dexteritas

Comment: I'm getting compile errors with your example. One error is that at `\begin{filecontents}{\bibliographietest.bib}` there should not be a backslash. But there are still other errors. Can you test, if your MWE works without errors?

Comment: Another error is that you need to add `\usepackage{setspace}` to use the command `\setstretch{1.0}`. That one is responsible for the "1.0", that shouldn't be in the output.