# biblatex error: Bibliography macro undefined

Tags: biblatex, footnotes

I am using Biblatex and have used the following code to create two different classes of footnotes, one with the citation and a regular foot note

```
\DeclareNewFootnote{A}
\DeclareNewFootnote{B}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}

\makeatletter
\newtoggle{cbx@togcite}

% Citation number superscript in brackets
\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{%
  \iftoggle{cbx@togcite}
    {\@textsuperscript{\normalfont[\@thefnmark]}\enspace #1}
    {\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}\enspace #1}%
  \global\togglefalse{cbx@togcite}}

% Citation number superscript in brackets (for babel french)
\ifdef{\@makefntextFB}{%
\renewcommand\@makefntextFB[1]{%
  \iftoggle{cbx@togcite}
    {\@textsuperscript{\normalfont[\@thefnmark]}\enspace #1}
    {\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}\enspace #1}%
  \global\togglefalse{cbx@togcite}}}{}

% See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/71566/35864
\let\cbx@savelist\@empty
\newcounter{cbx@inst@iter}
\newcounter{cbx@inst@lastonpage}
\setcounter{cbx@inst@lastonpage}{0}

\AtDataInput{%
  \csnumgdef{cbx@instcount@\thefield{entrykey}}{-1}}

% user-level citation command
\DeclareCiteCommand{\sfcite}[\cbx@superscript]
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \let\multicitedelim\supercitedelim
   \iffieldundef{prenote}{}{\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring prenote argument}}%
   \iffieldundef{postnote}{}{\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring postnote argument}}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:super:foot}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:comp}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}}

% save instcount, save key and last inline instcount if seen first on page
\newbibmacro*{cite:super:foot}{%
  \xdef\cbx@key{\thefield{entrykey}}%
  \ifsamepage{\value{instcount}}{\csuse{cbx@instcount@\cbx@key}}
    {}
    {\listxadd{\cbx@savelist}{\cbx@key}%
     \ifnumequal{\value{cbx@inst@lastonpage}}{0}%
       {\defcounter{cbx@inst@iter}{\value{instcount}}%
        \loop\ifnum\value{cbx@inst@iter}>0
          \ifsamepage{\value{instcount}}{\value{cbx@inst@iter}}
            {\ifcsundef{blx@fnpage@\the\value{cbx@inst@iter}}
               {\setcounter{cbx@inst@lastonpage}{\value{cbx@inst@iter}}}
               {}%
             \stepcounter{cbx@inst@iter}}
            {\setcounter{cbx@inst@iter}{0}}%
        \repeat}
       {}}%
  \csnumgdef{cbx@instcount@\cbx@key}{\value{instcount}}}

\newrobustcmd*{\cbx@superscript}[1]{%
  \mkbibsuperscript{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}%
  \cbx@footnote}

% defer citation footnotes to last inline reference instance on page
\newrobustcmd*{\cbx@footnote}{%
  \ifboolexpr{ not test {\ifdefempty{\cbx@savelist}}
               and test {\ifnumequal{\value{instcount}}{\value{cbx@inst@lastonpage}}} }
    {\cbx@sortlist@init%
     \let\do\cbx@do
     \dolistloop{\cbx@sortlist}%
     \global\let\cbx@savelist\@empty
     \setcounter{cbx@inst@lastonpage}{0}}
    {}}

% print footnotes in 'sorting' order
\def\cbx@do#1{%
  \ifinlist{#1}{\cbx@savelist}
    {\begingroup
     \blx@resetdata
     \blx@getdata@cite{#1}%
     \blx@setoptions@type\abx@field@entrytype
     \blx@setoptions@entry
     \blx@execute
     \blx@beglang
     \toggletrue{cbx@togcite}%
     \footnotetextA[\thefield{labelnumber}]{\blx@driver\abx@field@entrytype}%
     \blx@endlang
     \endgroup}
    {}}

% access internal list of sorted entry keys
\def\cbx@sortlist@init{%
  \global\letcs{\cbx@sortlist}
    {blx@dlist@entry@\the\c@refsection @\blx@refcontext@context}}
\let\cbx@sortlist\@empty
\makeatother


\newbibmacro{string+doiurlisbn}[1]{%
  \iffieldundef{doi}{%
    \iffieldundef{url}{%
      \iffieldundef{isbn}{%
       \iffieldundef{issn}{%
          #1%
        }{%
          \href{http://books.google.com/books?vid=ISSN\thefield{issn}}{#1}%
        }%
      }{%
        \href{http://books.google.com/books?vid=ISBN\thefield{isbn}}{#1}%
      }%
    }{%
      \href{\thefield{url}}{#1}%
    }%
  }{%
    \href{https://doi.org/\thefield{doi}}{#1}%
  }%
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{\usebibmacro{string+doiurlisbn}
{\mkbibemph{#1}}}
```

This code is taken from [This post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/342626/292520)

However when I cite using `\sfcite` no footnote number appears in th superscript
I get the errors that `cite:init`, `cite:comp` and `cite:dump` are undefined I thought this may be what is causing the problem

If it is relavant I am using the following options on biblatex

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, bibstyle=nature, citestyle = authoryear, natbib=true ,subentry, mcite, citetracker, pagetracker=page]{biblatex}
```

Also the entire citation appears in the footnote the same way as it does in the bibliography but I would like in the *authoryear* style but I cannot figure out what I need to change

Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{manyfoot}
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, bibstyle=nature, citestyle = authoryear, natbib=true ,subentry, mcite, citetracker, pagetracker=page]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{
  andothers = {\textit{et~al\adddot}}
}

\DeclareNewFootnote{A}
\DeclareNewFootnote{B}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}

\makeatletter
\newtoggle{cbx@togcite}

% Citation number superscript in brackets
\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{%
  \iftoggle{cbx@togcite}
    {\@textsuperscript{\normalfont[\@thefnmark]}\enspace #1}
    {\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}\enspace #1}%
  \global\togglefalse{cbx@togcite}}

% Citation number superscript in brackets (for babel french)
\ifdef{\@makefntextFB}{%
\renewcommand\@makefntextFB[1]{%
  \iftoggle{cbx@togcite}
    {\@textsuperscript{\normalfont[\@thefnmark]}\enspace #1}
    {\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}\enspace #1}%
  \global\togglefalse{cbx@togcite}}}{}

% See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/71566/35864
\let\cbx@savelist\@empty
\newcounter{cbx@inst@iter}
\newcounter{cbx@inst@lastonpage}
\setcounter{cbx@inst@lastonpage}{0}

\AtDataInput{%
  \csnumgdef{cbx@instcount@\thefield{entrykey}}{-1}}

% user-level citation command
\DeclareCiteCommand{\sfcite}[\cbx@superscript]
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \let\multicitedelim\supercitedelim
   \iffieldundef{prenote}{}{\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring prenote argument}}%
   \iffieldundef{postnote}{}{\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring postnote argument}}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:super:foot}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:comp}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}}

% save instcount, save key and last inline instcount if seen first on page
\newbibmacro*{cite:super:foot}{%
  \xdef\cbx@key{\thefield{entrykey}}%
  \ifsamepage{\value{instcount}}{\csuse{cbx@instcount@\cbx@key}}
    {}
    {\listxadd{\cbx@savelist}{\cbx@key}%
     \ifnumequal{\value{cbx@inst@lastonpage}}{0}%
       {\defcounter{cbx@inst@iter}{\value{instcount}}%
        \loop\ifnum\value{cbx@inst@iter}>0
          \ifsamepage{\value{instcount}}{\value{cbx@inst@iter}}
            {\ifcsundef{blx@fnpage@\the\value{cbx@inst@iter}}
               {\setcounter{cbx@inst@lastonpage}{\value{cbx@inst@iter}}}
               {}%
             \stepcounter{cbx@inst@iter}}
            {\setcounter{cbx@inst@iter}{0}}%
        \repeat}
       {}}%
  \csnumgdef{cbx@instcount@\cbx@key}{\value{instcount}}}

\newrobustcmd*{\cbx@superscript}[1]{%
  \mkbibsuperscript{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}%
  \cbx@footnote}

% defer citation footnotes to last inline reference instance on page
\newrobustcmd*{\cbx@footnote}{%
  \ifboolexpr{ not test {\ifdefempty{\cbx@savelist}}
               and test {\ifnumequal{\value{instcount}}{\value{cbx@inst@lastonpage}}} }
    {\cbx@sortlist@init%
     \let\do\cbx@do
     \dolistloop{\cbx@sortlist}%
     \global\let\cbx@savelist\@empty
     \setcounter{cbx@inst@lastonpage}{0}}
    {}}

% print footnotes in 'sorting' order
\def\cbx@do#1{%
  \ifinlist{#1}{\cbx@savelist}
    {\begingroup
     \blx@resetdata
     \blx@getdata@cite{#1}%
     \blx@setoptions@type\abx@field@entrytype
     \blx@setoptions@entry
     \blx@execute
     \blx@beglang
     \toggletrue{cbx@togcite}%
     \footnotetextA[\thefield{labelnumber}]{\blx@driver\abx@field@entrytype}%
     \blx@endlang
     \endgroup}
    {}}

% access internal list of sorted entry keys
\def\cbx@sortlist@init{%
  \global\letcs{\cbx@sortlist}
    {blx@dlist@entry@\the\c@refsection @\blx@refcontext@context}}
\let\cbx@sortlist\@empty
\makeatother


\newbibmacro{string+doiurlisbn}[1]{%
  \iffieldundef{doi}{%
    \iffieldundef{url}{%
      \iffieldundef{isbn}{%
       \iffieldundef{issn}{%
          #1%
        }{%
          \href{http://books.google.com/books?vid=ISSN\thefield{issn}}{#1}%
        }%
      }{%
        \href{http://books.google.com/books?vid=ISBN\thefield{isbn}}{#1}%
      }%
    }{%
      \href{\thefield{url}}{#1}%
    }%
  }{%
    \href{https://doi.org/\thefield{doi}}{#1}%
  }%
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{\usebibmacro{string+doiurlisbn}
{\mkbibemph{#1}}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Frank1953,
  author  = {Frank, F. C.},
  title   = {On spontaneous asymmetric synthesis},
  journal = {Biochim. Biophys. Acta},
  year    = {1953},
  volume  = {11},
  pages   = {459-463},
  doi     = {10.1016/0006-3002(53)90082-1},
  url     =
  {http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0006300253900821},
}

@article{Kagan1986,
  author  = {Puchot, C. and Samuel, O. and Dunach, E. and Zhao, S. and
             Agami, C. and Kagan, H. B.},
  title   = {Nonlinear effects in asymmetric synthesis.
             Examples in asymmetric oxidations and aldolization reactions},
  journal = {J. Am. Chem. Soc.},
  year    = {1986},
  volume  = {108},
  number  = {9},
  pages   = {2353-2357},
  doi     = {10.1021/ja00269a036},
}
@article{Soai1995,
  author  = {Soai, Kenso and Shibata, Takanori and Morioka, Hiroshi 
             and Choji, Kaori},
  title   = {Asymmetric autocatalysis and amplification of
             enantiomeric excess of a chiral molecule},
  journal = {Nature},
  year    = {1995},
  volume  = {378},
  number  = {6559},
  pages   = {767-768},
  doi     = {10.1038/378767a0},
}
@article{Brown2001,
  author  = {Blackmond, Donna G. and McMillan, Christopher R.
             and Ramdeehul, Shailesh and Schorm, Andrea and Brown, John M.},
  title   = {Origins of Asymmetric Amplification
             in Autocatalytic Alkylzinc Additions},
  journal = {J. Am. Chem. Soc.},
  year    = {2001},
  volume  = {123},
  number  = {41},
  pages   = {10103-10104},
  doi     = {10.1021/ja0165133},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\section{Title}
\null\vfill\noindent
Vanilla footnote.\footnoteB{Vanilla footnote text.}
First citation.\sfcite{Frank1953}
First citation.\sfcite{Kagan1986}
Vanilla footnote.\footnoteB{Vanilla footnote text.}
First ``multi'' citation.\sfcite{Frank1953,Kagan1986,Soai1995}
\newpage
\section{Title}
\null\vfill\noindent
Second citation.\sfcite{Frank1953}
Vanilla footnote.\footnoteB{Vanilla footnote text.}
Second citation.\sfcite{Soai1995}
Second citation.\sfcite{Kagan1986}\footnoteB{Vanilla footnote text.}
First citation.\sfcite{Brown2001}
\newpage
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This has been complied on overleaf using the *pdfLaTeX* compiler, I tried using biber as a backend however then I get the error *Citation is undefined* it just puts the reference name in the superscript,the footnote and bibliography disappear entirely

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please post the `MWE` as in executable format

Comment: A **MWE** Has been added to the main post thanks!

Comment: Thank you for the response! I am using OverLeaf so I think it shouldn't be a problem. And setting the backend to biber makes things worse

Comment: @Dai Bowen sorry I wasnt more specific I recompiled from scratch after changing the backend to biber and like I said the authoryear now shows up in the superscript , the footnotes and the bibliography completely disappear. I tried it again but got the same result it seems biber canot find the citations at all I get the error that the citation is undefined

Comment: Ah, your MWE compiles fine with `style=chem-angew`, so this is probably coming from changes to the styles that ship with biblatex so they no longer provide  the `cite:init` etc bib macros.

Comment: @Dai Bown That seems to make sense though I cannot seem to find a workaround or fix, could you please suggest asolution?

Comment: @Prakrut I had a go rewriting some of the macros based on what I found in http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/latex/cbx/authoryear.cbx but I'm not too familiar with biblatex's internals and couldn't figure out all the errors, I'll try and come back later, or somebody else with more experience may swing by.