# How to horizontally align text within longer footnotes (and footcites that are displayed at the bottom of the page) that range over several lines

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, horizontal-alignment, footnotes

I am using the code below to achieve footnotes and footcites and the bottom of the page using the `manyfoot` package.

Everything that was used for the code can be found here: [Biblatex cite with footnote only once, with use of brackets](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20787/biblatex-cite-with-footnote-only-once-with-use-of-brackets) and [Biblatex footcite: customizing biblatex and bibliography style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/342485/biblatex-footcite-customizing-biblatex-and-bibliography-style) and [How to cut out a prefix in the doi field if present](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/342876/how-to-cut-out-a-prefix-in-the-doi-field-if-present)

Further, moewe's solution ([Get rid of undesired vertical spacing within single footnotes (and footcites that are displayed at the bottom of the page) due to setspace settings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/542792/get-rid-of-undesired-vertical-spacing-within-single-footnotes-and-footcites-tha)) redefining the `manyfoot` equivalent of `\@footnotetext` enabled nice, uniform spacing within the footnote part at the bottom of the page while changing the line spacing with the `setspace` package.

Still, I do not like that the text within longer footnotes and citations that range across more than one line is not aligned on the left side, but rather it starts at the very beginning of the second line aligned with the number for the respective footnote/footcite (see attached picture that results from the MWE).

How can I achieve the desired alignment within longer footnotes? (the '10103' should start at the same position as the 'D.', and 'Vanilla' should start at the same position as 'This')

MWE:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt,DIV=11]{scrbook}
\usepackage[USenglish]{babel}       % General language setting & Hyphenation; vor newpxtext laden!
\frenchspacing                      % Deaktiviert /Nonfrenchspacing von USenglish
\usepackage{newpxtext}
\usepackage{newpxmath}
\linespread{1.05}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.3}

\usepackage{xcolor}                 
\usepackage{manyfoot}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=chem-angew,mcite,subentry]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}               
\hypersetup{%
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor={red!0!black},
    citecolor={blue!0!black},
    urlcolor={blue!80!black}
}

\makeatletter
\long\def\MFL@fnoteplain#1#2#3{\NCC@makefnmark{#2}%
  \MFL@insert#1{\def\baselinestretch {\setspace@singlespace}%
    \reset@font\footnotesize
    \interlinepenalty\interfootnotelinepenalty
    \hsize\MFL@columnwidth \@parboxrestore
    \protected@edef\@currentlabel{\@thefnmark}%
    \color@begingroup
      \MFL@applyhook{#1}%
      \@makefntext{%
        \rule\z@\footnotesep\ignorespaces#3\@finalstrut\strutbox}%
    \color@endgroup
  }%
}
\makeatother

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{citetracker=true,sorting=none,maxcitenames=10,doi=false,url=false,isbn=false,hyperref=true,backref=false}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{
   andothers = {\textit{et~al\adddot}}            
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Citation footnotes: use \footnoteA
\DeclareNewFootnote{A}

% Vanilla footnotes: use \footnoteB
\DeclareNewFootnote{B}

% Number of each bibliography entry in brackets
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}

\makeatletter

\newtoggle{cbx@togcite}

% Citation number superscript in brackets
\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{%
  \iftoggle{cbx@togcite}
    {\@textsuperscript{\normalfont[\@thefnmark]}\enspace #1}
    {\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}\enspace #1}%
  \global\togglefalse{cbx@togcite}}

% Citation number superscript in brackets (for babel french)
\ifdef{\@makefntextFB}{%
\renewcommand\@makefntextFB[1]{%
  \iftoggle{cbx@togcite}
    {\@textsuperscript{\normalfont[\@thefnmark]}\enspace #1}
    {\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}\enspace #1}%
  \global\togglefalse{cbx@togcite}}}{}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Mostly verbatim from Joseph Wright
% http://www.texdev.net/2010/03/08/biblatex-numbered-citations-as-footnotes/

\DeclareCiteCommand{\sfcite}[\cbx@superscript]%
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \let\multicitedelim=\supercitedelim
   \iffieldundef{prenote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring prenote argument}}%
   \iffieldundef{postnote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring postnote argument}}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{sfcite}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:comp}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}}

\newbibmacro*{sfcite}{%
  \ifciteseen
  {}
  {\xappto\cbx@citehook{%
   \global\toggletrue{cbx@togcite}%
   \noexpand\footnotetextA[\thefield{labelnumber}]{%
     \fullcite{\thefield{entrykey}}\addperiod}}}}

\newrobustcmd{\cbx@superscript}[1]{%
  \mkbibsuperscript{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}%
  \cbx@citehook%
  \global\let\cbx@citehook=\empty}

\let\cbx@citehook=\empty

\makeatother

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newbibmacro{string+doiurlisbn}[1]{%
  \iffieldundef{doi}{%
    \iffieldundef{url}{%
      \iffieldundef{isbn}{%
        \iffieldundef{issn}{%
          #1%
        }{%
          \href{http://books.google.com/books?vid=ISSN\thefield{issn}}{#1}%
        }%
      }{%
        \href{http://books.google.com/books?vid=ISBN\thefield{isbn}}{#1}%
      }%
    }{%
      \href{\thefield{url}}{#1}%
    }%
  }{%
    \href{https://doi.org/\thefield{doi}}{#1}%
  }%
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{\usebibmacro{string+doiurlisbn}{\mkbibemph{#1}}}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[
        fieldsource=doi,
        match=\regexp{https?://(dx.)?doi.org/(.+)},
        replace=\regexp{$2}%$
      ]
    }
  }
}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{Frank1953,
  author  = {Frank, F. C.},
  title   = {On spontaneous asymmetric synthesis},
  journal = {Biochim. Biophys. Acta},
  year    = {1953},
  volume  = {11},
  pages   = {459-463},
  doi     = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0006-3002(53)90082-1},
  url     = {http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0006300253900821},
}

@Article{Kagan1986,
  author  = {Puchot, C. and Samuel, O. and Dunach, E. and Zhao, S. and Agami, C. and Kagan, H. B.},
  title   = {Nonlinear effects in asymmetric synthesis. Examples in asymmetric oxidations and aldolization reactions},
  journal = {J. Am. Chem. Soc.},
  year    = {1986},
  volume  = {108},
  number  = {9},
  pages   = {2353-2357},
  doi     = {10.1021/ja00269a036},
  url     = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/ja00269a036},
}

@article{Soai1995,
   author = {Soai, Kenso and Shibata, Takanori and Morioka, Hiroshi and Choji, Kaori},
   title = {Asymmetric autocatalysis and amplification of enantiomeric excess of a chiral molecule},
   journal = {Nature},
   year = {1995},
   volume = {378},
   number = {6559},
   pages = {767-768},
   url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1038/378767a0}
}

@Article{Brown2001,
  author  = {Blackmond, Donna G. and McMillan, Christopher R. and Ramdeehul, Shailesh and Schorm, Andrea and Brown, John M.},
  title   = {Origins of Asymmetric Amplification in Autocatalytic Alkylzinc Additions},
  journal = {J. Am. Chem. Soc.},
  year    = {2001},
  volume  = {123},
  number  = {41},
  pages   = {10103-10104},
  doi     = {10.1021/ja0165133},
  url     = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/ja0165133},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}



\begin{document}
\chapter{Title}
\null\vfill\noindent
Vanilla footnote.\footnoteB{This is a very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long Vanilla footnote text.}
First citation.\sfcite{Frank1953} Some random text here.
First citation.\sfcite{Brown2001}
Vanilla footnote.\footnoteB{Vanilla footnote text.}
First ``multi'' citation.\sfcite{Frank1953,Brown2001,Soai1995}
\chapter{Title}
\null\vfill\noindent
Second citation.\sfcite{Frank1953}
Vanilla footnote.\footnoteB{Vanilla footnote text.}
Second citation.\sfcite{Soai1995}
Second citation.\sfcite{Brown2001}\footnoteB{Vanilla footnote text.}
First citation.\sfcite{Kagan1986}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For hanging indent in the footnotes you need to change the footnote setup a bit. (Note that there are a lot of players involved here: `scrbook`, whose footnote setup is overwritten by `manyfoot`, `manyfoot` and our own definitions that are pasted over `manyfoot`.)

Replace

```
% Citation footnotes: use \footnoteA
\DeclareNewFootnote{A}

% Vanilla footnotes: use \footnoteB
\DeclareNewFootnote{B}
```

with

```
% Citation footnotes: use \footnoteA
\SetFootnoteHook{%
  \hangindent=1.8em\noindent}
\DeclareNewFootnote{A}

% Vanilla footnotes: use \footnoteB
\SetFootnoteHook{%
  \hangindent=1.8em\noindent}
\DeclareNewFootnote{B}
```

and

```
% Citation number superscript in brackets
\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{%
  \iftoggle{cbx@togcite}
    {\@textsuperscript{\normalfont[\@thefnmark]}\enspace #1}
    {\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}\enspace #1}%
  \global\togglefalse{cbx@togcite}}

% Citation number superscript in brackets (for babel french)
\ifdef{\@makefntextFB}{%
\renewcommand\@makefntextFB[1]{%
  \iftoggle{cbx@togcite}
    {\@textsuperscript{\normalfont[\@thefnmark]}\enspace #1}
    {\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}\enspace #1}%
  \global\togglefalse{cbx@togcite}}}{}
```

with

```
% Citation number superscript in brackets
\newcommand*{\cbx@makefntext}[1]{%
  \hb@xt@1.8em{%
  \iftoggle{cbx@togcite}
    {\@textsuperscript{\normalfont[\@thefnmark]}}
    {\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}}%
  \hss}%
  #1%
  \global\togglefalse{cbx@togcite}}

\renewcommand*{\@makefntext}{\cbx@makefntext}

% Citation number superscript in brackets (for babel french)
\ifdef{\@makefntextFB}
  {\renewcommand\@makefntextFB{\cbx@makefntext}}
  {}
```

Then

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt,DIV=11]{scrbook}
\usepackage[USenglish]{babel}       % General language setting & Hyphenation; vor newpxtext laden!
\frenchspacing                      % Deaktiviert /Nonfrenchspacing von USenglish
\usepackage{newpxtext}
\usepackage{newpxmath}
\linespread{1.05}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.3}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{manyfoot}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=chem-angew,mcite,subentry]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{%
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor={red!0!black},
    citecolor={blue!0!black},
    urlcolor={blue!80!black}
}

\makeatletter
\long\def\MFL@fnoteplain#1#2#3{\NCC@makefnmark{#2}%
  \MFL@insert#1{\def\baselinestretch {\setspace@singlespace}%
    \reset@font\footnotesize
    \interlinepenalty\interfootnotelinepenalty
    \hsize\MFL@columnwidth \@parboxrestore
    \protected@edef\@currentlabel{\@thefnmark}%
    \color@begingroup
      \MFL@applyhook{#1}%
      \@makefntext{%
        \rule\z@\footnotesep\ignorespaces#3\@finalstrut\strutbox}%
    \color@endgroup
  }%
}
\makeatother

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{citetracker=true,sorting=none,maxcitenames=10,doi=false,url=false,isbn=false,hyperref=true,backref=false}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{
   andothers = {\textit{et~al\adddot}}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Citation footnotes: use \footnoteA
\SetFootnoteHook{%
  \hangindent=1.8em\noindent}
\DeclareNewFootnote{A}

% Vanilla footnotes: use \footnoteB
\SetFootnoteHook{%
  \hangindent=1.8em\noindent}
\DeclareNewFootnote{B}

% Number of each bibliography entry in brackets
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}

\makeatletter

\newtoggle{cbx@togcite}

% Citation number superscript in brackets
\newcommand*{\cbx@makefntext}[1]{%
  \hb@xt@1.8em{%
  \iftoggle{cbx@togcite}
    {\@textsuperscript{\normalfont[\@thefnmark]}}
    {\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}}%
  \hss}%
  #1%
  \global\togglefalse{cbx@togcite}}

\renewcommand*{\@makefntext}{\cbx@makefntext}

% Citation number superscript in brackets (for babel french)
\ifdef{\@makefntextFB}
  {\renewcommand\@makefntextFB{\cbx@makefntext}}
  {}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Mostly verbatim from Joseph Wright
% http://www.texdev.net/2010/03/08/biblatex-numbered-citations-as-footnotes/

\DeclareCiteCommand{\sfcite}[\cbx@superscript]%
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \let\multicitedelim=\supercitedelim
   \iffieldundef{prenote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring prenote argument}}%
   \iffieldundef{postnote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring postnote argument}}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{sfcite}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:comp}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}}

\newbibmacro*{sfcite}{%
  \ifciteseen
  {}
  {\xappto\cbx@citehook{%
   \global\toggletrue{cbx@togcite}%
   \noexpand\footnotetextA[\thefield{labelnumber}]{%
     \fullcite{\thefield{entrykey}}\addperiod}}}}

\newrobustcmd{\cbx@superscript}[1]{%
  \mkbibsuperscript{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}%
  \cbx@citehook%
  \global\let\cbx@citehook=\empty}

\let\cbx@citehook=\empty

\makeatother

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newbibmacro{string+doiurlisbn}[1]{%
  \iffieldundef{doi}{%
    \iffieldundef{url}{%
      \iffieldundef{isbn}{%
        \iffieldundef{issn}{%
          #1%
        }{%
          \href{http://books.google.com/books?vid=ISSN\thefield{issn}}{#1}%
        }%
      }{%
        \href{http://books.google.com/books?vid=ISBN\thefield{isbn}}{#1}%
      }%
    }{%
      \href{\thefield{url}}{#1}%
    }%
  }{%
    \href{https://doi.org/\thefield{doi}}{#1}%
  }%
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{\usebibmacro{string+doiurlisbn}{\mkbibemph{#1}}}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[
        fieldsource=doi,
        match=\regexp{https?://(dx.)?doi.org/(.+)},
        replace=\regexp{$2}%$
      ]
    }
  }
}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{filecontents}[force]{\jobname.bib}
@article{Frank1953,
  author  = {Frank, F. C.},
  title   = {On spontaneous asymmetric synthesis},
  journal = {Biochim. Biophys. Acta},
  year    = {1953},
  volume  = {11},
  pages   = {459-463},
  doi     = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0006-3002(53)90082-1},
  url     = {http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0006300253900821},
}

@article{Kagan1986,
  author  = {Puchot, C. and Samuel, O. and Dunach, E. and Zhao, S.
             and Agami, C. and Kagan, H. B.},
  title   = {Nonlinear effects in asymmetric synthesis. Examples in
             asymmetric oxidations and aldolization reactions},
  journal = {J. Am. Chem. Soc.},
  year    = {1986},
  volume  = {108},
  number  = {9},
  pages   = {2353-2357},
  doi     = {10.1021/ja00269a036},
}
@article{Soai1995,
  author  = {Soai, Kenso and Shibata, Takanori and Morioka, Hiroshi
             and Choji, Kaori},
  title   = {Asymmetric autocatalysis and amplification of enantiomeric
             excess of a chiral molecule},
  journal = {Nature},
  year    = {1995},
  volume  = {378},
  number  = {6559},
  pages   = {767-768},
  doi     = {10.1038/378767a0}
}
@article{Brown2001,
  author  = {Blackmond, Donna G. and McMillan, Christopher R.
             and Ramdeehul, Shailesh and Schorm, Andrea and Brown, John M.},
  title   = {Origins of Asymmetric Amplification in Autocatalytic
             Alkylzinc Additions},
  journal = {J. Am. Chem. Soc.},
  year    = {2001},
  volume  = {123},
  number  = {41},
  pages   = {10103-10104},
  doi     = {10.1021/ja0165133},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}



\begin{document}
\chapter{Title}
\null\vfill\noindent
Vanilla footnote.\footnoteB{This is a very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long Vanilla footnote text.}
First citation.\sfcite{Frank1953} Some random text here.
First citation.\sfcite{Brown2001}
Vanilla footnote.\footnoteB{Vanilla footnote text.}
First ``multi'' citation.\sfcite{Frank1953,Brown2001,Soai1995}
\chapter{Title}
\null\vfill\noindent
Second citation.\sfcite{Frank1953}
Vanilla footnote.\footnoteB{Vanilla footnote text.}
Second citation.\sfcite{Soai1995}
Second citation.\sfcite{Brown2001}\footnoteB{Vanilla footnote text.}
First citation.\sfcite{Kagan1986}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

produces

[image: footnotes with hanging indent.]

Comment: This is so great - thank you so much, moewe!! Do you know of any way to suppress the warnings that come from this very citation style (Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) detected at line 215, etc.)? You can imagine that in my original document, the number of warnings became very large.

Comment: @Sacharja Oh, yeah, I forgot a line. Should be fixed now.

Comment: Works perfectly fine! Thanks again!