# How to evenly increase the vertical spacing within manyfoot footnotes?

Tags: biblatex, spacing, citing, footnotes, line-spacing

I am using the code below to achieve footnotes and footcites at the bottom of the page using the manyfoot package.

Everything that was used for the code can be found here: [Biblatex cite with footnote only once, with use of brackets](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20787/biblatex-cite-with-footnote-only-once-with-use-of-brackets) and [Biblatex footcite: customizing biblatex and bibliography style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/342485/biblatex-footcite-customizing-biblatex-and-bibliography-style) and [How to cut out a prefix in the doi field if present](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/342876/how-to-cut-out-a-prefix-in-the-doi-field-if-present) and [Get rid of undesired vertical spacing within single footnotes (and footcites that are displayed at the bottom of the page) due to setspace settings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/542792/get-rid-of-undesired-vertical-spacing-within-single-footnotes-and-footcites-tha) and [How to horizontally align text within longer footnotes (and footcites that are displayed at the bottom of the page) that range over several lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/542927/how-to-horizontally-align-text-within-longer-footnotes-and-footcites-that-are-d)

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt,DIV=11]{scrbook}
\usepackage[USenglish]{babel}       % General language setting & Hyphenation; vor newpxtext laden!
\frenchspacing                      % Deaktiviert /Nonfrenchspacing von USenglish
\usepackage{newpxtext}
\usepackage{newpxmath}
\linespread{1.05}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.3}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{manyfoot}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=chem-angew,mcite,subentry]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{%
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor={red!0!black},
    citecolor={blue!0!black},
    urlcolor={blue!80!black}
}

\makeatletter
\long\def\MFL@fnoteplain#1#2#3{\NCC@makefnmark{#2}%
  \MFL@insert#1{\def\baselinestretch {\setspace@singlespace}%
    \reset@font\footnotesize
    \interlinepenalty\interfootnotelinepenalty
    \hsize\MFL@columnwidth \@parboxrestore
    \protected@edef\@currentlabel{\@thefnmark}%
    \color@begingroup
      \MFL@applyhook{#1}%
      \@makefntext{%
        \rule\z@\footnotesep\ignorespaces#3\@finalstrut\strutbox}%
    \color@endgroup
  }%
}
\makeatother

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{citetracker=true,sorting=none,maxcitenames=10,doi=false,url=false,isbn=false,hyperref=true,backref=false}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{
   andothers = {\textit{et~al\adddot}}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Citation footnotes: use \footnoteA
\SetFootnoteHook{%
  \hangindent=1.8em\noindent}
\DeclareNewFootnote{A}

% Vanilla footnotes: use \footnoteB
\SetFootnoteHook{%
  \hangindent=1.8em\noindent}
\DeclareNewFootnote{B}

% Number of each bibliography entry in brackets
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}

\makeatletter

\newtoggle{cbx@togcite}

% Citation number superscript in brackets
\newcommand*{\cbx@makefntext}[1]{%
  \hb@xt@1.8em{%
  \iftoggle{cbx@togcite}
    {\@textsuperscript{\normalfont[\@thefnmark]}}
    {\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}}%
  \hss}%
  #1%
  \global\togglefalse{cbx@togcite}}

\renewcommand*{\@makefntext}{\cbx@makefntext}

% Citation number superscript in brackets (for babel french)
\ifdef{\@makefntextFB}
  {\renewcommand\@makefntextFB{\cbx@makefntext}}
  {}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Mostly verbatim from Joseph Wright
% http://www.texdev.net/2010/03/08/biblatex-numbered-citations-as-footnotes/

\DeclareCiteCommand{\sfcite}[\cbx@superscript]%
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \let\multicitedelim=\supercitedelim
   \iffieldundef{prenote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring prenote argument}}%
   \iffieldundef{postnote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring postnote argument}}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{sfcite}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:comp}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}}

\newbibmacro*{sfcite}{%
  \ifciteseen
  {}
  {\xappto\cbx@citehook{%
   \global\toggletrue{cbx@togcite}%
   \noexpand\footnotetextA[\thefield{labelnumber}]{%
     \fullcite{\thefield{entrykey}}\addperiod}}}}

\newrobustcmd{\cbx@superscript}[1]{%
  \mkbibsuperscript{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}%
  \cbx@citehook%
  \global\let\cbx@citehook=\empty}

\let\cbx@citehook=\empty

\makeatother

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newbibmacro{string+doiurlisbn}[1]{%
  \iffieldundef{doi}{%
    \iffieldundef{url}{%
      \iffieldundef{isbn}{%
        \iffieldundef{issn}{%
          #1%
        }{%
          \href{http://books.google.com/books?vid=ISSN\thefield{issn}}{#1}%
        }%
      }{%
        \href{http://books.google.com/books?vid=ISBN\thefield{isbn}}{#1}%
      }%
    }{%
      \href{\thefield{url}}{#1}%
    }%
  }{%
    \href{https://doi.org/\thefield{doi}}{#1}%
  }%
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{\usebibmacro{string+doiurlisbn}{\mkbibemph{#1}}}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[
        fieldsource=doi,
        match=\regexp{https?://(dx.)?doi.org/(.+)},
        replace=\regexp{$2}%$
      ]
    }
  }
}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{filecontents}[force]{\jobname.bib}
@article{Frank1953,
  author  = {Frank, F. C.},
  title   = {On spontaneous asymmetric synthesis},
  journal = {Biochim. Biophys. Acta},
  year    = {1953},
  volume  = {11},
  pages   = {459-463},
  doi     = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0006-3002(53)90082-1},
  url     = {http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0006300253900821},
}

@article{Kagan1986,
  author  = {Puchot, C. and Samuel, O. and Dunach, E. and Zhao, S.
             and Agami, C. and Kagan, H. B.},
  title   = {Nonlinear effects in asymmetric synthesis. Examples in
             asymmetric oxidations and aldolization reactions},
  journal = {J. Am. Chem. Soc.},
  year    = {1986},
  volume  = {108},
  number  = {9},
  pages   = {2353-2357},
  doi     = {10.1021/ja00269a036},
}
@article{Soai1995,
  author  = {Soai, Kenso and Shibata, Takanori and Morioka, Hiroshi
             and Choji, Kaori},
  title   = {Asymmetric autocatalysis and amplification of enantiomeric
             excess of a chiral molecule},
  journal = {Nature},
  year    = {1995},
  volume  = {378},
  number  = {6559},
  pages   = {767-768},
  doi     = {10.1038/378767a0}
}
@article{Brown2001,
  author  = {Blackmond, Donna G. and McMillan, Christopher R.
             and Ramdeehul, Shailesh and Schorm, Andrea and Brown, John M.},
  title   = {Origins of Asymmetric Amplification in Autocatalytic
             Alkylzinc Additions},
  journal = {J. Am. Chem. Soc.},
  year    = {2001},
  volume  = {123},
  number  = {41},
  pages   = {10103-10104},
  doi     = {10.1021/ja0165133},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
\chapter{Title}
\null\vfill\noindent
Vanilla footnote.\footnoteB{This is a very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long Vanilla footnote text.}
First citation.\sfcite{Frank1953} Some random text here.
First citation.\sfcite{Brown2001}
Vanilla footnote.\footnoteB{Vanilla footnote text.}
First ``multi'' citation.\sfcite{Frank1953,Brown2001,Soai1995}
\chapter{Title}
\null\vfill\noindent
Second citation.\sfcite{Frank1953}
Vanilla footnote.\footnoteB{Vanilla footnote text.}
Second citation.\sfcite{Soai1995}
Second citation.\sfcite{Brown2001}\footnoteB{Vanilla footnote text.}
First citation.\sfcite{Kagan1986}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

moewe's solution redefining the manyfoot equivalent of @footnotetext enabled nice, uniform spacing within the footnote part at the bottom of the page.

Now I would like to slightly increase the vertical spacing within footnotes (that is a uniform spacing between and within (!) footnotes). Increasing the linespread with `\linespread{1.05}` does not affect footnotes anymore. Using `\setstretch{1.3}` of the `setspace` package does not affect these footnotes as well. moewe suggested to play around with `\footnotesep` by changing `\setlength{\footnotesep}{2\footnotesep}`, but this only changes the spacing between the footnotes (and not within footnotes that go across multiple lines).

Example 1: `\linespread{1.05}` and `\setstretch{1.3}`
[image]

Example 2: `\linespread{2.00}` and `\setstretch{2.0}`
[image]

Example 3: `\linespread{1.05}` and `\setstretch{1.3}` and `\setlength{\footnotesep}{2\footnotesep}`
[image]

How to evenly increase the vertical spacing within these footnotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [Get rid of undesired vertical spacing within single footnotes (and footcites that are displayed at the bottom of the page) due to setspace settings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/542792/35864) we explicitly switched footnotes back to single-spacing regardless of what the global `\setstretch` might be. If you want `\setstretch` to apply to footnotes as well, remove the `\def\baselinestretch {\setspace@singlespace}%`. Since that was the whole point of redefining `\MFL@fnoteplain` in the first place, you can just *remove* the whole block

```
\makeatletter
\long\def\MFL@fnoteplain#1#2#3{\NCC@makefnmark{#2}%
  \MFL@insert#1{\def\baselinestretch {\setspace@singlespace}%
    \reset@font\footnotesize
    \interlinepenalty\interfootnotelinepenalty
    \hsize\MFL@columnwidth \@parboxrestore
    \protected@edef\@currentlabel{\@thefnmark}%
    \color@begingroup
      \MFL@applyhook{#1}%
      \@makefntext{%
        \rule\z@\footnotesep\ignorespaces#3\@finalstrut\strutbox}%
    \color@endgroup
  }%
}
\makeatother
```

With that redefinition out of the way, `\setstretch` applies to footnotes again and enlarges the line spacing there as well (so the space *within* footnotes is enlarged).

The space *between* footnotes is controlled by `\footnotesep`, you can multiply that length by any factor easily with

```
\setlength{\footnotesep}{<factor>\footnotesep}
```

In the MWE I chose the factor 2 to exaggerate the effect, but you can of course change the two `2`s to `1.3`.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt,DIV=11]{scrbook}
\usepackage[USenglish]{babel}       % General language setting & Hyphenation; vor newpxtext laden!
\frenchspacing                      % Deaktiviert /Nonfrenchspacing von USenglish
\usepackage{newpxtext}
\usepackage{newpxmath}
\usepackage{setspace}

\setstretch{2}
\setlength{\footnotesep}{2\footnotesep}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{manyfoot}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=chem-angew,mcite,subentry]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{%
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor={red!0!black},
    citecolor={blue!0!black},
    urlcolor={blue!80!black}
}


\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{citetracker=true,
  sorting=none,
  maxcitenames=10,
  doi=false, url=false, isbn=false,
  backref=false}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{
   andothers = {\textit{et~al\adddot}}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Citation footnotes: use \footnoteA
\SetFootnoteHook{%
  \hangindent=1.8em\noindent}
\DeclareNewFootnote{A}

% Vanilla footnotes: use \footnoteB
\SetFootnoteHook{%
  \hangindent=1.8em\noindent}
\DeclareNewFootnote{B}

% Number of each bibliography entry in brackets
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}

\makeatletter

\newtoggle{cbx@togcite}

% Citation number superscript in brackets
\newcommand*{\cbx@makefntext}[1]{%
  \hb@xt@1.8em{%
  \iftoggle{cbx@togcite}
    {\@textsuperscript{\normalfont[\@thefnmark]}}
    {\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}}%
  \hss}%
  #1%
  \global\togglefalse{cbx@togcite}}

\renewcommand*{\@makefntext}{\cbx@makefntext}

% Citation number superscript in brackets (for babel french)
\ifdef{\@makefntextFB}
  {\renewcommand\@makefntextFB{\cbx@makefntext}}
  {}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Mostly verbatim from Joseph Wright
% http://www.texdev.net/2010/03/08/biblatex-numbered-citations-as-footnotes/

\DeclareCiteCommand{\sfcite}[\cbx@superscript]%
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \let\multicitedelim=\supercitedelim
   \iffieldundef{prenote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring prenote argument}}%
   \iffieldundef{postnote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring postnote argument}}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{sfcite}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:comp}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}}

\newbibmacro*{sfcite}{%
  \ifciteseen
  {}
  {\xappto\cbx@citehook{%
   \global\toggletrue{cbx@togcite}%
   \noexpand\footnotetextA[\thefield{labelnumber}]{%
     \fullcite{\thefield{entrykey}}\addperiod}}}}

\newrobustcmd{\cbx@superscript}[1]{%
  \mkbibsuperscript{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}%
  \cbx@citehook%
  \global\let\cbx@citehook=\empty}

\let\cbx@citehook=\empty

\makeatother

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newbibmacro{string+doiurlisbn}[1]{%
  \iffieldundef{doi}{%
    \iffieldundef{url}{%
      \iffieldundef{isbn}{%
        \iffieldundef{issn}{%
          #1%
        }{%
          \href{http://books.google.com/books?vid=ISSN\thefield{issn}}{#1}%
        }%
      }{%
        \href{http://books.google.com/books?vid=ISBN\thefield{isbn}}{#1}%
      }%
    }{%
      \href{\thefield{url}}{#1}%
    }%
  }{%
    \href{https://doi.org/\thefield{doi}}{#1}%
  }%
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{\usebibmacro{string+doiurlisbn}{\mkbibemph{#1}}}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[
        fieldsource=doi,
        match=\regexp{https?://(dx.)?doi.org/(.+)},
        replace=\regexp{$2}%$
      ]
    }
  }
}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{filecontents}[force]{\jobname.bib}
@article{Frank1953,
  author  = {Frank, F. C.},
  title   = {On spontaneous asymmetric synthesis},
  journal = {Biochim. Biophys. Acta},
  year    = {1953},
  volume  = {11},
  pages   = {459-463},
  doi     = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0006-3002(53)90082-1},
  url     = {http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0006300253900821},
}

@article{Kagan1986,
  author  = {Puchot, C. and Samuel, O. and Dunach, E. and Zhao, S.
             and Agami, C. and Kagan, H. B.},
  title   = {Nonlinear effects in asymmetric synthesis. Examples in
             asymmetric oxidations and aldolization reactions},
  journal = {J. Am. Chem. Soc.},
  year    = {1986},
  volume  = {108},
  number  = {9},
  pages   = {2353-2357},
  doi     = {10.1021/ja00269a036},
}
@article{Soai1995,
  author  = {Soai, Kenso and Shibata, Takanori and Morioka, Hiroshi
             and Choji, Kaori},
  title   = {Asymmetric autocatalysis and amplification of enantiomeric
             excess of a chiral molecule},
  journal = {Nature},
  year    = {1995},
  volume  = {378},
  number  = {6559},
  pages   = {767-768},
  doi     = {10.1038/378767a0}
}
@article{Brown2001,
  author  = {Blackmond, Donna G. and McMillan, Christopher R.
             and Ramdeehul, Shailesh and Schorm, Andrea and Brown, John M.},
  title   = {Origins of Asymmetric Amplification in Autocatalytic
             Alkylzinc Additions},
  journal = {J. Am. Chem. Soc.},
  year    = {2001},
  volume  = {123},
  number  = {41},
  pages   = {10103-10104},
  doi     = {10.1021/ja0165133},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
\chapter{Title}
\null\vfill\noindent
\lipsum

Vanilla footnote.\footnoteB{This is a very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long Vanilla footnote text.}
First citation.\sfcite{Frank1953} Some random text here.
First citation.\sfcite{Brown2001}
Vanilla footnote.\footnoteB{Vanilla footnote text.}
First ``multi'' citation.\sfcite{Frank1953,Brown2001,Soai1995}
\chapter{Title}
\null\vfill\noindent
Second citation.\sfcite{Frank1953}
Vanilla footnote.\footnoteB{Vanilla footnote text.}
Second citation.\sfcite{Soai1995}
Second citation.\sfcite{Brown2001}\footnoteB{Vanilla footnote text.}
First citation.\sfcite{Kagan1986}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Wide footnote spacing.]

---

If you want a different inter-line spacing in footnotes than in your normal text, you can bring back the redefinition of `\MFL@fnoteplain` and force a different value in `\baselinestretch`

```
\makeatletter
\long\def\MFL@fnoteplain#1#2#3{\NCC@makefnmark{#2}%
  \MFL@insert#1{\def\baselinestretch {4}%
    \reset@font\footnotesize
    \interlinepenalty\interfootnotelinepenalty
    \hsize\MFL@columnwidth \@parboxrestore
    \protected@edef\@currentlabel{\@thefnmark}%
    \color@begingroup
      \MFL@applyhook{#1}%
      \@makefntext{%
        \rule\z@\footnotesep\ignorespaces#3\@finalstrut\strutbox}%
    \color@endgroup
  }%
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Sorry, I was not precise enough: I do want different spacing in footnotes than in the normal text. So basically your last point changing `\baselinestretch` should address my problem, but unfortunately changing `\baselinestretch {x}` leads to non-uniform spacing within the footnotes (try for example `\baselinestretch {1.1}`, `\baselinestretch {2}` and `\baselinestretch {4}`) Does it work for you?

Comment: @Sacharja I'm not quite sure what you mean, but if I synchronise the `\baselinestretch` in `\MFL@fnoteplain` and the scale factor of `\footnotesep` (e.g. `\def\baselinestretch {2}` & `\setlength{\footnotesep}{2\footnotesep}`) I get something that looks fairly even (to my - admittedly - very untrained eye, anyway). Of course you can still change the two independently in a fine-tuning process in case you are not entirely happy with the result. Just play with all the values a bit.

Comment: Great, it worked! I forgot to change `\setlength{\footnotesep}{x\footnotesep}`. I agree, it looks pretty even. Thanks moewe.