# Showing title of inbook & article with chem-angew biblatex style only in bibliography and not in the footnote(cite)?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing, footnotes, biblatex-chem

I am using the code below to achieve footnotes and footcites at the bottom of the page using the manyfoot package, biblatex and the chem-angew style.

Everything that was used for the code can be found here: [Biblatex cite with footnote only once, with use of brackets](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20787/biblatex-cite-with-footnote-only-once-with-use-of-brackets)  and [Biblatex footcite: customizing biblatex and bibliography style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/342485/biblatex-footcite-customizing-biblatex-and-bibliography-style) and [How to cut out a prefix in the doi field if present](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/342876/how-to-cut-out-a-prefix-in-the-doi-field-if-present) and [How to horizontally align text within longer footnotes (and footcites that are displayed at the bottom of the page) that range over several lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/542927/how-to-horizontally-align-text-within-longer-footnotes-and-footcites-that-are-d)

I want to show the title of `article` and `inbook` in the bibliography (without quotation marks), but not in the footnotes when the article or the inbook chapter is cited. Using `chaptertitle=true,articletitle=true`, I get the titles in the bibliography but also in the footnotes. How do I achieve my desired citation style?

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt,DIV=11]{scrbook}
\usepackage[USenglish]{babel}       % General language setting & Hyphenation; vor newpxtext laden!
\frenchspacing                      % Deaktiviert /Nonfrenchspacing von USenglish
\usepackage{newpxtext}
\usepackage{newpxmath}
\linespread{1.05}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.3}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{manyfoot}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=chem-angew,mcite,subentry]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{%
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor={red!0!black},
    citecolor={blue!0!black},
    urlcolor={blue!80!black}
}

\makeatletter
\long\def\MFL@fnoteplain#1#2#3{\NCC@makefnmark{#2}%
  \MFL@insert#1{\def\baselinestretch {\setspace@singlespace}%
    \reset@font\footnotesize
    \interlinepenalty\interfootnotelinepenalty
    \hsize\MFL@columnwidth \@parboxrestore
    \protected@edef\@currentlabel{\@thefnmark}%
    \color@begingroup
      \MFL@applyhook{#1}%
      \@makefntext{%
        \rule\z@\footnotesep\ignorespaces#3\@finalstrut\strutbox}%
    \color@endgroup
  }%
}
\makeatother

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{citetracker=true,sorting=none,maxcitenames=2,maxbibnames=99,chaptertitle=true,articletitle=true,doi=false,url=false,isbn=false,hyperref=true,backref=false}
\urlstyle{same}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article,inbook]{citetitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,inbook]{title}{#1} 


\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{
   andothers = {\textit{et~al\adddot}}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Citation footnotes: use \footnoteA
\SetFootnoteHook{%
  \hangindent=1.8em\noindent}
\DeclareNewFootnote{A}

% Vanilla footnotes: use \footnoteB
\SetFootnoteHook{%
  \hangindent=1.8em\noindent}
\DeclareNewFootnote{B}

% Number of each bibliography entry in brackets
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}

\makeatletter

\newtoggle{cbx@togcite}

% Citation number superscript in brackets
\newcommand*{\cbx@makefntext}[1]{%
  \hb@xt@1.8em{%
  \iftoggle{cbx@togcite}
    {\@textsuperscript{\normalfont[\@thefnmark]}}
    {\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}}%
  \hss}%
  #1%
  \global\togglefalse{cbx@togcite}}

\renewcommand*{\@makefntext}{\cbx@makefntext}

% Citation number superscript in brackets (for babel french)
\ifdef{\@makefntextFB}
  {\renewcommand\@makefntextFB{\cbx@makefntext}}
  {}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Mostly verbatim from Joseph Wright
% http://www.texdev.net/2010/03/08/biblatex-numbered-citations-as-footnotes/

\DeclareCiteCommand{\sfcite}[\cbx@superscript]%
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \let\multicitedelim=\supercitedelim
   \iffieldundef{prenote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring prenote argument}}%
   \iffieldundef{postnote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring postnote argument}}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{sfcite}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:comp}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}}

\newbibmacro*{sfcite}{%
  \ifciteseen
  {}
  {\xappto\cbx@citehook{%
   \global\toggletrue{cbx@togcite}%
   \noexpand\footnotetextA[\thefield{labelnumber}]{%
     \fullcite{\thefield{entrykey}}\addperiod}}}}

\newrobustcmd{\cbx@superscript}[1]{%
  \mkbibsuperscript{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}%
  \cbx@citehook%
  \global\let\cbx@citehook=\empty}

\let\cbx@citehook=\empty

\makeatother

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newbibmacro{string+doiurlisbn}[1]{%
  \iffieldundef{doi}{%
    \iffieldundef{url}{%
      \iffieldundef{isbn}{%
        \iffieldundef{issn}{%
          #1%
        }{%
          \href{http://books.google.com/books?vid=ISSN\thefield{issn}}{#1}%
        }%
      }{%
        \href{http://books.google.com/books?vid=ISBN\thefield{isbn}}{#1}%
      }%
    }{%
      \href{\thefield{url}}{#1}%
    }%
  }{%
    \href{https://doi.org/\thefield{doi}}{#1}%
  }%
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{\usebibmacro{string+doiurlisbn}{\mkbibemph{#1}}}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[
        fieldsource=doi,
        match=\regexp{https?://(dx.)?doi.org/(.+)},
        replace=\regexp{$2}%$
      ]
    }
  }
}



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{filecontents}[force]{\jobname.bib}
@article{Frank1953,
  author  = {Frank, F. C.},
  title   = {On spontaneous asymmetric synthesis},
  journal = {Biochim. Biophys. Acta},
  year    = {1953},
  volume  = {11},
  pages   = {459-463},
  doi     = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0006-3002(53)90082-1},
  url     = {http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0006300253900821},
}
@inbook{Keim1987,
   author = {Keim, W.},
   title = {Industrial Uses of Carbon Dioxide},
   booktitle = {Carbon Dioxide as a Source of Carbon: Biochemical and Chemical Uses},
   editor = {Aresta, M. and Forti, G.},
   publisher = {Springer},
   address = {Dordrecht},
   edition = {1},
   ISBN = {978-94-009-3923-3},
   DOI = {10.1007/978-94-009-3923-3},
   url = {https://doi.org/10.1007/978-94-009-3923-3},
   year = {1987},
   type = {Book Section}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}



\begin{document}
\chapter{Title}
\null\vfill\noindent
Vanilla footnote.\footnoteB{Vanilla footnote text.}
Citation of article.\sfcite{Frank1953} Citation of inbook.\sfcite{Keim1987}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The options `articletitle` and `chaptertitle` are implemented via a simple `etoolbox` toggle that can be switched anywhere in your document.

Here you could say

```
\AtEveryCite{%
  \togglefalse{bbx:articletitle}%
  \togglefalse{bbx:chaptertitle}%
}
```

to toggle the titles off only in citations.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt,DIV=11]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[USenglish]{babel}       % General language setting & Hyphenation; vor newpxtext laden!
\frenchspacing                      % Deaktiviert /Nonfrenchspacing von USenglish
\usepackage{newpxtext}
\usepackage{newpxmath}
\linespread{1.05}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.3}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{manyfoot}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=chem-angew,mcite,subentry]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{%
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor={red!0!black},
    citecolor={blue!0!black},
    urlcolor={blue!80!black}
}

\makeatletter
\long\def\MFL@fnoteplain#1#2#3{\NCC@makefnmark{#2}%
  \MFL@insert#1{\def\baselinestretch {\setspace@singlespace}%
    \reset@font\footnotesize
    \interlinepenalty\interfootnotelinepenalty
    \hsize\MFL@columnwidth \@parboxrestore
    \protected@edef\@currentlabel{\@thefnmark}%
    \color@begingroup
      \MFL@applyhook{#1}%
      \@makefntext{%
        \rule\z@\footnotesep\ignorespaces#3\@finalstrut\strutbox}%
    \color@endgroup
  }%
}
\makeatother

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{citetracker=true,
  sorting=none,
  maxcitenames=2, maxbibnames=99,
  chaptertitle=true, articletitle=true,
  doi=false, url=false, isbn=false,
  backref=false}
\urlstyle{same}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article,inbook]{citetitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,inbook]{title}{#1} 

\AtEveryCite{%
  \togglefalse{bbx:articletitle}%
  \togglefalse{bbx:chaptertitle}%
}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{
   andothers = {\textit{et~al\adddot}}
}

% Citation footnotes: use \footnoteA
\SetFootnoteHook{%
  \hangindent=1.8em\noindent}
\DeclareNewFootnote{A}

% Vanilla footnotes: use \footnoteB
\SetFootnoteHook{%
  \hangindent=1.8em\noindent}
\DeclareNewFootnote{B}

% Number of each bibliography entry in brackets
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}

\makeatletter

\newtoggle{cbx@togcite}

% Citation number superscript in brackets
\newcommand*{\cbx@makefntext}[1]{%
  \hb@xt@1.8em{%
  \iftoggle{cbx@togcite}
    {\@textsuperscript{\normalfont[\@thefnmark]}}
    {\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}}%
  \hss}%
  #1%
  \global\togglefalse{cbx@togcite}}

\renewcommand*{\@makefntext}{\cbx@makefntext}

% Citation number superscript in brackets (for babel french)
\ifdef{\@makefntextFB}
  {\renewcommand\@makefntextFB{\cbx@makefntext}}
  {}

% Mostly verbatim from Joseph Wright
% http://www.texdev.net/2010/03/08/biblatex-numbered-citations-as-footnotes/

\DeclareCiteCommand{\sfcite}[\cbx@superscript]%
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \let\multicitedelim=\supercitedelim
   \iffieldundef{prenote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring prenote argument}}%
   \iffieldundef{postnote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring postnote argument}}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{sfcite}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:comp}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}}

\newbibmacro*{sfcite}{%
  \ifciteseen
  {}
  {\xappto\cbx@citehook{%
   \global\toggletrue{cbx@togcite}%
   \noexpand\footnotetextA[\thefield{labelnumber}]{%
     \fullcite{\thefield{entrykey}}\addperiod}}}}

\newrobustcmd{\cbx@superscript}[1]{%
  \mkbibsuperscript{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}%
  \cbx@citehook%
  \global\let\cbx@citehook=\empty}

\let\cbx@citehook=\empty

\makeatother

\newbibmacro{string+doiurlisbn}[1]{%
  \iffieldundef{doi}{%
    \iffieldundef{url}{%
      \iffieldundef{isbn}{%
        \iffieldundef{issn}{%
          #1%
        }{%
          \href{http://books.google.com/books?vid=ISSN\thefield{issn}}{#1}%
        }%
      }{%
        \href{http://books.google.com/books?vid=ISBN\thefield{isbn}}{#1}%
      }%
    }{%
      \href{\thefield{url}}{#1}%
    }%
  }{%
    \href{https://doi.org/\thefield{doi}}{#1}%
  }%
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{\usebibmacro{string+doiurlisbn}{\mkbibemph{#1}}}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[
        fieldsource=doi,
        match=\regexp{https?://(dx.)?doi.org/(.+)},
        replace=\regexp{$2}%$
      ]
    }
  }
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Frank1953,
  author  = {Frank, F. C.},
  title   = {On spontaneous asymmetric synthesis},
  journal = {Biochim. Biophys. Acta},
  year    = {1953},
  volume  = {11},
  pages   = {459-463},
  doi     = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0006-3002(53)90082-1},
  url     = {http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0006300253900821},
}
@inbook{Keim1987,
   author = {Keim, W.},
   title = {Industrial Uses of Carbon Dioxide},
   booktitle = {Carbon Dioxide as a Source of Carbon: Biochemical and Chemical Uses},
   editor = {Aresta, M. and Forti, G.},
   publisher = {Springer},
   address = {Dordrecht},
   edition = {1},
   ISBN = {978-94-009-3923-3},
   DOI = {10.1007/978-94-009-3923-3},
   url = {https://doi.org/10.1007/978-94-009-3923-3},
   year = {1987},
   type = {Book Section}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
\null\vfill\noindent
Vanilla footnote.\footnoteB{Vanilla footnote text.}
Citation of article.\sfcite{Frank1953} Citation of inbook.\sfcite{Keim1987}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Citation: "F. C. Frank, Biochim. Biophys. Acta 1953, 11, 459–463.", bibliography: "F. C. Frank, On spontaneous asymmetric synthesis, Biochim. Biophys. Acta 1953, 11, 459–463."]

Comment: Works great, like every time - thanks moewe!